# Remembering SQL connection state in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, connection-pooling, dapper, sqlconnection

*Beside's  the old known fact that `connection.Close()` vs `connection.Dispose()` are the same  - except that running `Close()` over a disposed connection raises an exception while running `Close()` over a closed connection - is OK - I still have a question :*

Assuming connection pooling is on , (default)  - *why* is it important to remember  the state of the connection  ?

I've read [*this question here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439409/open-close-sqlconnection-or-keep-open) which shows that - *avoiding opening and closing a connection saves performance*.

This  seems logic , but the problem is that the connection is *never* actually closed ! it is only *marked* for close.

Even If I use it under a `using` scope  - the dispose just *closes* the connection and put it back in the pool.

Even if I wanted , I couldn't leave it open *( because I'd want others to use it)*. so I had to close/dispose it.

[Looking at Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET45/SqlMapperAsync.cs#L27)  which also implements this behavior:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(this...)
        {
         //...
            bool wasClosed = cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed;
            using (var cmd = (DbCommand)command.SetupCommand(cnn, info.ParamReader))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (wasClosed) await ((DbConnection)cnn).OpenAsync()...
                  //...
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (wasClosed) cnn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see the "memorization" is implemented  here.

*nb , I already asked Marc about a related topic which is  - why in dapper samples he uses both `GetClosedConneciton` and `GetOpenConnection` and I got an answer which is to show - that Dapper can deal with both scenarios. However this current question is about why it is **re-set**  the connections state.*

**Question :**

Looking at Dapper code it seems that it remembers the state and re-set the state after operation. ( I also know this behavior from the old sqldataadapter class)

The question is  - why ?  If I got a closed  connection  - then, I need to open it. great. but why do I have to close it by condition ? why not ALWAYS close it ? it's not going to hurt performance since the connection is not actually closed -  it is only returned to pool.

The other way around  - If I got an open connection ,  then I'd do work and keep it *open* (huh??)

AS you probably see , I'm missing something here. can someone please shed  light ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why not ALWAYS close it ?

The user could be doing lots of work on that connection. It could be associated with a transaction (closing would orphan it). It could have temporary tables (closing would destroy  them), or other connection-preserved state (`SET` options, impersonation, etc).

Closing a connection here (if it was open originally) would be an unusual and unexpected thing with multiple nasty side-effects.

Answer (score 6):

If you're writing a library function where it makes sense for the consumers to pass you a connection object (of whatever flavour) then the safest thing to do is to respect that connection:

- if you're passed an open connection object, make no assumptions about it and certainly don't close it after you've completed your work - you don't know what your consumers have done with it or will do with it.
- if you're passed a closed connection object, then you'd better open it before you attempt to use it, and you ought to close it after you're done - you know that your consumer can't have e.g. a transaction open against a closed connection.

If *your* code creates a connection object, then I'd always recommend that the creation be placed in a `using` statement and so it will always be closed when you're done.

So, the only remaining thing I can think to say is to think carefully about writing your functions and work out whether it makes *sense* for your consumers to be passing you connection objects - if your work should always be performed in isolation, it would make more sense to ask for e.g. a connection string and for your code to entirely control the connection.