# Open/Close database in ASP.NET Core for every SQL command

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I write simple ASP.NET Core app where Controller injects MyService (configured as Scoped) that in turn injects MyDbContext.

In my controller's method I have 2 database queries and my debug output looks like this:

```
 Executing action method...
 Opening connection to database 'shell' on server 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5432'.
 ...
 Closing connection to database 'shell' on server 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5432'.
 Opening connection to database 'shell' on server 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5432'.
 ...
 Closing connection to database 'shell' on server 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5432'.
 Request finished in...
```

The question is: Is it correct to open a new connection on each request and even more - to open a new connection for each sql command? Can't it establish the connection to database once and reuse it. Wouldn't it be much better for performance?

PS: I use PostgreSQL with npgsql provider

Comment: You instantiate a new database context everytime you want to do something, and make sure it is minimized to the scope of that action. The connection pooling is abstracted away and managed by EF else where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like someone else mentioned. Connection pooling is your friend.

The opening and closing is perfectly fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4439434/3799142

Comment: How can I turn on connection pooling in ef-core?

Comment: @Rem. If you already use the 'using' statement it will dispose everything for you and you don't have to worry about anything! :)

Comment: I thought 'using' deals with disposing of connection. And pooling is about reusing them

Comment: @Rem https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx Have a look at that article and spefically under "Adding connections". You will find the statement: "Connections are released back into the pool when they are closed or disposed".

I personally use the 'using' statement as it's easier to forget .Open and .Close

Comment: So connection pooling is always on? PS: I do not use connections per se, I use LINQ expressions and LINQ deals with connections

Comment: @Rem It depends on the provider. npgsql has pooling on by default. http://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html. Check the parameter "pooling" :) 

If you would like to turn this off. You would set that in your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Always open and close the connection as already mentioned [all over SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4439434/3799142). [Connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) deals with your performance issues.

Makes your code easier to read and you will never have to worry about, where is that connection i have to open, is it open? Isn't it closed somewhere else?

As you are asking, I assume you dont really want to. This is what I generally do. A small wrapper method which would fire your sql commands simmilar to this.

```
static bool FireCommand(SqlCommand command)
{
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteQuery();
    command.Connection.Close();
 }
```