# C#: Execute a query from Windows Forms using TextBoxes and a Button

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, t-sql

How I can change my code, so I can search for specific columns of my table?

I want to write the request's column values in TextBoxes, and then execute the request when I press a Button.

```
private async void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label77.Visible) label77.Visible = false;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox62.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox62.Text))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Policlinic] ('id_Policlinic', 'Name', 'Address', 'Phone') VALUES (" + textBox62 + ", '" + textBox62 + "', '" + textBox62 + "','" + textBox62 + "')", sqlConnection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@id_Policlinic", SqlDbType.Int); command.Parameters["@id_Policlinic"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox62.Text, 4);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox62.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address", textBox62.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", textBox62.Text);
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        label77.Visible = true;
        label77.Text = "Поля должны быть заполнены!";
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Write code in button click event to search in the database table by the value entered in the textbox.

Comment: I would recommend naming your text boxes, buttons, and labels something useful, for example instead of `textBox62` it could be `txtName`. I'm also assuming you don't want to use `textBox62` for the name, address, and phone number? Your current code doesn't do anything other than insert into the database, so I'm not sure what kind of "search by column" you are talking about?

Comment: I intentionally left the names created automatically, for ease of understanding. I'm trying to figure out how I can change my code so that it works as I planned.

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov: are you using Microsoft's SQL Server?

Comment: Yes i'm use Microsoft's SQL Server

Comment: Is your `sqlConnection` open?

Comment: Yes, sqlConnection opened, need programming only button with textBox

Comment: Anatoliy, leaving the automatically created names will make things **harder** to understand, not easier. If you refer the control in your code anywhere, it should have a name that has more meaning than just a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to summarize what you should do in the code below to run this query.

Just remember to replace that `textBox62` by something else more suitable.

Make sure you have the right sever address and the right credentials before creating the connection.

After executing the query, you should not keep the connection open for a long time ([read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439409/open-close-sqlconnection-or-keep-open)).

```
private void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (label77.Visible) label77.Visible = false;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox62.Text))
    {
        label77.Visible = true;
        label77.Text = "Поля должны быть заполнены!";
        return;
    }

    SqlConnection connection = null;
    SqlCommand command = null;
    try
    {
        // First create a SQL Connection:
        string connectionString = $"Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName";
        Credential credential = new SqlCredential("myusername", "mypassword");
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString, credential);
        connection.Open();

        // Then create the SQL command:
        command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.[Policlinic] (Name, Address, Phone) VALUES (@Name, @Address, @Phone)";

        // Add '@' in front of all column names:
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", textBox62.Text, 60)
        {
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        });
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Address", textBox62.Text, 120)
        {
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        });
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Phone", textBox62.Text, 20)
        {
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        });

        // Execute command:
        Task.Run(() => command.ExecuteNonQuery()).Wait();

        // Parse any results here...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null) ex = ex.InnerException;
        MessageBox.Show(this, ex.ToString(), "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        // Now cleanup this mess:
        command?.Dispose();
        connection?.Close();
        connection?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Let me know the error message in case you're still in trouble executing that.

Comment: program crashes

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov: Found another issue in your code: the SQL query is wrong.

Comment: MS VStudio writes - unjustifiable justification

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov: Is the "id_Policlinic" column of type INT IDENTITY in the "dbo.Policlinic" table? If so, you should not set the value, because it will be automatically assigned by the database.

Comment: id_Policlinic this is surrogate key. I have a connection to the database. creating a new connection is not a good idea, I think that you only need to create a query with an existing connection.

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov: You probably mean a 'primary' key. Pay special attention to this line of code: connection.CreateCommand()  -  you must have a valid connection. What is your current error?

Comment: @AnatoliyChurikov It's not good practice in .Net to try to re-use the same connection object throughout your program. ADO.Net has a feature called Connection Pooling that is already doing this in the background, and trying to re-use the same connection object interferes with how it operates. You really do need to create a brand new SqlConnection object instance in most situations.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp A surrogate key is an ID key used in place of a natural key. For example, a "Person" table may have a natural key of SSN or username. Using an auto-increment/identity ID# field to the table as the primary key makes that key a surrogate key. So they are interchangeable here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: In this case, Anatoliy Churikov shouldn't be inserting values into the id_Policlinic column, since they are auto-generated by the server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private async void button26_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //why check the SAME textbox twice?
    // You should give MEANINGFUL NAMES to your controls, rather than leaving them at the default
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox62.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox62.Text)) 
    {
        label77.Visible = true;
        label77.Text = "Поля должны быть заполнены!";
        return;
    }
    label77.Visible = false;

    string sql = "INSERT INTO [Policlinic] (Name, Address, Phone) VALUES ( @Name, @Address, @Phone);";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {  
        //Use exact database column types and lengths here
        // DON'T trust ADO.Net to guess these types correctly.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = textBox62.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 80).Value =  textBox62.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 14).Value =  textBox62.Text;

        con.Open()
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

There are a number of important changes here:

1. Do NOT try to re-use the same `SqlConnection` object throughout your application. This interferes with the built-in connection pooling.
2. Do NOT trust ADO.Net to *guess* your parameter types and lengths.
3. DO rely on `using` blocks to the make sure your connection object is disposed, even if an exception is thrown.

If you're still learning how to do this stuff, I also recommend removing  `async`/`await` for the time being, and just calling `ExecuteNonQuery()`. Add that stuff back *after* you have it working in the "normal" way.

Comment: Thanks for _Do NOT trust ADO.Net to guess your parameter types and lengths_