# maintain one ODBC connection or connect/dispose each use?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, odbc

In my application, I have a function that executes SQL lines that can be called several hundreds of times depending on what the user decides to do.  Would it be better to have the application open a connection at the start and re-use that connection throughout the user session to execute commands as they are needed or to have the function open the connection, execute the SQL line, and close the connection each time a procedure needs to be executed?

Sorry if this is a pretty basic or general question - just curious if there's a "best practice".

Thanks!

Randy

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["open/close" SqlConnection or keep open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439409/open-close-sqlconnection-or-keep-open)

Comment: thanks for the link - it did give some additional insight but the answers almost seem to boil down to a preference / case-by-case basis - I get the impression that if i have a slew of SQL lines to execute one after another then keep the connection open - otherwise if there's going to be idle time then close the connection