# Data reader already open

Tags: vb.net, sqldatareader

Have already looked questions similar to mine but none of them works for me this is my code

```
dbconn = New SqlConnection
    dbconn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=JENELIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=feeding_monitoring_system;User ID=sa;Password=Jenelie19; MultipleActiveResultSets = true")
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Try
        dbconn.Open()
        Dim sql As String
        sql = "select Count (Gender) as NumberofStudent, Gender from Student_Info Group by Gender"
        dbcomm = New SqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        reader = dbcomm.ExecuteReader
        sda.SelectCommand = dbcomm
        sda.Fill(ds, "Student_Info")
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        dbconn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Then at sda.Fill(ds, "Student_Info") an error happens
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c)

Comment: The exception means what it says - you just opened a Reader 2 lines before.   Dont create what you dont need and ***all*** your DBProvider objects should be used inside `Using` blocks

Comment: You dont use that reader, what are you doing there?

Comment: *Don't* declare variables outside the scope they are used and *don't* use `New ` with them. That creates a new object that's discarded as soon as a new one is assigned to the variable. For example, writing `Dim dbcomm = New SqlCommand(sql, dbconn)` is enough to create a new command *inside* the try block. So is `Dim reader = dbcomm.ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Furthermore, you need to make certain that connection, reader objects are properly disposed by using a `Using` block

Comment: And you should not expose your passwords on a public site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont use that reader at all, so i don't understand your code. You want to fill the `DataSet` with the `DataAdapter`, then this is needed (always use `Using`):

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()

Using dbconn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=JENELIE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=feeding_monitoring_system;User ID=sa;Password=Jenelie19;MultipleActiveResultSets = true")
    Dim sda = New SqlDataAdapter("select Count (Gender) as NumberofStudent, Gender from Student_Info Group by Gender", dbconn)
    Try
        sda.Fill(ds, "Student_Info") ' you dont need to open/close the connection
    Catch ex As SqlException
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Using
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try making sure that all disposable objects are properly disposed within this function. I recommend the `Using` statement to help ensure that any disposable object gets properly disposed as it goes out of scope. I believe that `SqlConnection`, `SqlDataReader`, `SqlDataAdapter` and `DataSet` are all disposable.

**Edit:** Although I think Tim's answer is more targeted at your problem (the `SqlDataReader` is unused and unnecessary), you should make sure to clean-up all your disposable objects, too. If you *do* use an SqlDataReader, you'll want to dispose of it before doing anything else, unless you're just trying to prove that you *can* have multiple result sets open at once, in which case, the lack of cleanup in multiple accesses to the same connection might be responsible (if one of them doesn't include MultipleActiveResultSets).

Comment: using statement disposes and the act of disposing closes the connection

Comment: @Aaron.S There is no `using` statement in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

First off, in that situation, you do not need to use reader, you just need SQLDataAdapter.

Second, you should use Conn.Close() to close your SQL connection, rather than Conn.Dispose(). The error means that some where in your code, you opened the connection before hand, but never closed it.

Comment: `Conn.Close()` is [not absolutely neccesary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195829/do-i-have-to-close-a-sqlconnection-before-it-gets-disposed)

Comment: In most cases `Close()` and `Dispose()` do the exact same thing.

Comment: @MatSnow please clarify your comment.  Close is not necessary if a using statement is used, correct?  if no using statement is used then Close is necessary

Comment: @AustinS90 your example is correct because he did NOT wrap his code into a using.  a using will dispose and that closes too

Comment: @Aaron.S Yes, just wanted to say, Conn.Dispose() will close the connection too.

Comment: @MatSnow you are correct but Dispose also disposes the object too which might not be desired.  if you want to reuse the object then you would need to new it again if Dispose were called instead of just Close