# Checking for Objects that implement IDisposable but aren't properly disposed

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Is there a way to automatically check existing C# source code for instances of objects that are not properly disposed of ie. using try / catch / finally or using statements?
Or do I need to just manually look at the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) for VS2010 - I believe they restored the [DisposeObjectsBeforeLeavingScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289%28VS.100%29.aspx) rule - which may do exactly what you want.

Comment: I downloaded the Trial version of VS2010 Premium and it does indeed have this rule CA2000. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Use FX Cop for a rule to check if IDisposable are placed in a proper Using block...
- You can use reflector to go through the object with IDisposable
- Ref.: [Is there a list of common object that implement IDisposable for the using statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033334/is-there-a-list-of-common-object-that-implement-idisposable-for-the-using-stateme) for additional idea

HTH

Answer (score 0):

CodeRush has some support for spotting *obvious* variants of this. Another possible option is (perhaps via an optional compilation symbol) add a finalizer to your own `IDisposable` objects, and complain loudly if they get finalized without being disposed (set a bool flag in the `Dispose`). But note: having a finalizer  changes the behaviour of the objects, so don't leave it in production code (or even your regular unit tests).