# using only possible for specific types?

Tags: c#, scope

The following doesn't work:

```
    public string foo()
    {
        using (Random myRandomChoice = new Random())
        {
            return myRandomChoice.Next(10).ToString();
        }
    }
```

The following is errors:

```
    public string foo()
    {
        Random myRandomChoice = new Random();
        return myRandomChoice.Next(10).ToString();
    }
```

The error message for the first `foo` is concerning `Random` not being implicitly convertable to `System.IDisposable`.

Is this a deliberate ploy withing the syntax of the language so you only use `using` in specific circumstances e.g when dealing with database connections? or can I explicitly convert `Random` to type `IDisposable` so that the initial `foo` works?

Is there a list available of types that would be better declared with `using` ?

Comment: The goal of IDisposable is not to be compatible with using, but is to help to manage unmanaged resources (File handles, connections to DB, etC.). Using is only a syntax sugar to simplify the call to the Dispose method. Do you mean that you use using to reduce scope of variable?

Comment: Any type that implements IDisposable can be used in a using statement. See my answer for how to find those types.

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567138/when-should-i-use-using-blocks-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033334/is-there-a-list-of-common-object-that-implement-idisposable-for-the-using-statem (this one is rather neat as it gives you a way to list all classes that implement IDisposable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `using` statement is a way to guarantee that `Dispose` is called on an object even when an exception is thrown. It is therefore meaningless when the object does not implement `IDisposable`.

The following code examples are equivalent:

(1) A using statement:

```
using (MyClass myObj = new MyClass())
{
    ...
}
```

(2) Disposing in a `finally` block:

```
try
{
    MyClass myObj = new MyClass();
    ...
}
finally
{
    myObj.Dispose();
}
```

As you can see, all the using statement achieves is disposal of the object, therefore it makes no sense if you object doesn't implement IDisposable.

[FXCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476.aspx) has a rule for checking that you have used `using` statements for your `IDisposable` types. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033334/177018) for other ways to find which types implement `IDisposable` and can be used in a using statement.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

See [using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The object provided to the using statement **must implement the
>   IDisposable interface**. This interface provides the Dispose method,
>   which should release the object's resources.

Since `Random` does not implement `System.IDisposable`, that is why you get the error.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> As a rule, when you use an IDisposable object, you should declare and
>   instantiate it in a using statement. The using statement calls the
>   Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it
>   as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope
>   as soon as Dispose is called. Within the using block, the object is
>   read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned.

Answer (score 1):

`using` is possible to execute on types that implement `IDisposable`.

In this way implemented Dispose(..) method on *that* type will be executed as soon as execution of the program jumps out of `using` block.

it's nothing else then "alias" for `try/finally` construct, injected by compiler in `IL`

Answer (score 1):

`using` is a better syntactic way of calling the dispose on IDisposable ( probably in a try-finally):

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an
>   exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can
>   achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and
>   then calling Dispose in a finally block;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: ok - so similar result to `try-finally`. But my question is that `using` can't always be the correct structure to use as not _all_ types work with it. Is there a list of the types which are good with `using`?