# Error loading sql parameters in a loop, VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, for-loop, parameters

I am currently working in Microsoft visual studio express 2013 with an sql back end. I am trying to run a loop through 2 comboboxes and a datetimepicker for any instance a checkbox is checked. However, I am running into an error that reads "System.ArgumentException: No Mapping exists from Object type system.windows.forms.datetimepicker to a known managed provider native type." When I run the code I have put a watch on the parameter value and it is not saving the data into the variable before the sql command fires. I think I need to store the variable in a different way to allow access to the variable. Here is my code:

```vb
Try

Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
    conn1.Open()
    Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT isnull(max(AuditID) + 1, 1) as 'AuditID' FROM table1", conn1)
        Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = comm1.ExecuteReader
        reader1.Read()
        Dim AuditID As Integer = reader1("AuditID")
        reader1.Dispose()

        'Loop through all checkboxes and write into sql tables
        Dim Run As Integer
        For Run = 1 To 5
            Dim LineItem = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CB" & Run), CheckBox)
            If LineItem.Checked = True Then
                Dim DateTime = DirectCast(Me.Controls("DTP" & Run), DateTimePicker)
                Dim Frequency = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBWeek" & Run), ComboBox)
                Dim Repeat = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBRepeat" & Run), ComboBox)

                'sql statements
                'select ID
                Using conn2 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                    conn2.Open()
                    Using comm2 As New SqlCommand("SELECT isnull(max(AuditID) + 1, 1) as 'ID' FROM table1", conn1)
                        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comm2.ExecuteReader
                        reader.Read()
                        Dim ID As Integer = reader("ID")
                        reader.Dispose()

                        'Insert into table audit line
                        Using conn3 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
                            conn3.Open()
                            Using comm3 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (ID, AuditID, DateStart, Freq, repeats) " _
                                                          & "VALUES (@ID, @AuditID, @DateStart, @Freq, @Repeats)", conn3)
                                With comm3.Parameters
                                    .AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
                                    .AddWithValue("@AuditID", AuditID)
                                    .AddWithValue("@DateStart", DateTime)
                                    .AddWithValue("@Freq", Frequency)
                                    .AddWithValue("@Repeats", Repeat)
                                End With
                                comm3.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            End Using
                            conn3.Close()
                        End Using
                    End Using
                    conn2.Close()
                End Using
            End If
        Next
    End Using
    conn1.Close()
End Using

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
```

My try statement stop my code on this line:

```vb
 comm3.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

However, I know that this error is coming from when I add my parameters, specifically these 3 lines:

```vb
.AddWithValue("@DateStart", DateTime)
.AddWithValue("@Freq", Frequency)
.AddWithValue("@Repeats", Repeat)
```

I am trying to get tese variables with a loop statement based on the design name here:

```vb
Dim DateTime = DirectCast(Me.Controls("DTP" & Run), DateTimePicker)
Dim Frequency = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBWeek" & Run), ComboBox)
Dim Repeat = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBRepeat" & Run), ComboBox)
```

It does not seem like the program likes using these dimensions above to be inserted into the sql table. Does anyone know a way I can carry these values over to the sql parameters statement?

Comment: Thanks for the code edit plutonix, I was just trying to figure that one out.

Comment: you should turn on Option Strict

Comment: Care to tell me how to do that?

Comment: Project Properties => Compile => Option Strict CBO to ON.  or `Option Strict On` at the top of each source file

Comment: you have several dubious type conversions:  `Dim DateTime = DirectCast(Me.Controls("DTP" & Run), DateTimePicker)`  first, DateTime is a type so it is a bad name, but here it will contain a Control after the cast.  Later `.AddWithValue("@DateStart", DateTime)` is trying to add the control to the DB rather than the `.Value` of that control

Comment: Ahhh, so I need to use variables to convert them to the .value type.

Comment: the same with the others - if you fix the DTP it will reveal the same problem with Frequency

Comment: 'code'  Dim Time As Date = DateTime.Value

Comment: you can also specify more than one object per Using block.  "Stacking"  `comm3` and `conn3` would reduce indentation.  Also, you could use the same connection object for both parts.  for a "stacking" example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28322399/1070452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things I would do differently.  First and always, use `Option Strict`, it will catch some of the type conversion you have going on.

I would get the controls from an explicit list rather then fetching from `Controls`.  Just make a few arrays to hold the control refs so you do not need to to find them in the collection:

```vb
Private DTPs As DateTimePicker() = {DTP1, DTP2...}
```

This will avoid the need to cast them, fewer hoops and implied converts like `"DTP" & Run`:

```vb
Dim dt As DateTime           ' vars for the SQL
Dim freq As Integer
For Run As Integer = 0 To 4
    dt = DTPs(Run).Value
    freq = cboFreq(Run).SelectedValue
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem, I needed to put my loop variables into .value type variables. I added this to fix it:

```
              Dim DateTime = DirectCast(Me.Controls("DTP" & Run), DateTimePicker)
                        Dim Frequency = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBWeek" & Run), ComboBox)
                        Dim Repeat = DirectCast(Me.Controls("CBRepeat" & Run), ComboBox)



                        Dim Time As Date = DateTime.Value
                        Dim Freq As Integer = Frequency.SelectedValue
                        Dim Again As Integer = Repeat.SelectedValue
```