# How to destroy an object in C#

Tags: c#

How to destroy an object in a condition?
for example:

```
Car c = new Car()
if (something)
//destroy car
```

I have tried to set the object to null but it didn`t work...

Comment: Can you define `destroy`?

Comment: Also, how do you know that it didn't work?

Comment: @Erik Philips - Not sure why this was marked as a duplicate.  This question doesn't ask about IDisposable.  Furthermore, IDisposable does not destroy the object, it just allows cleaning up of resources, so the other question doesn't answer this question at all.

Answer (score 2):

In addtion to setting your object as null , you should also remove it from other objects which refrences it as well
if you class uses resources that needs to be freed up use IDisposable

```
public class Car: IDisposable
{
    // free resources
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing that OP mentioned in the question that requires to use `IDisposable` which is used usually for unmanged resources.

Comment: Correct , but since this is a very general question , a more general answer seemed appropriate

Comment: what should I put in the method?

Comment: freeing Unmanaged resources if you class uses any , or also writing to a log

Comment: What do you mean by saying unmanaged resources?

Comment: see here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433197/what-exactly-are-unmanaged-resources

Answer (score 1):

set `c = null;`  As long as there are no other references to it, the garbage collector will destroy it the next time it runs.

Comment: this is not works for me

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  What behavior do you see after you set it to null that you're not expecting?

Comment: this is my code:
`Car c = new Car();
 c = null;
 Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Yes, that code should work fine.  The GC should destroy the object.  Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: because I tried...

Comment: @D4NieLDev - What did you try that made you think it didn't work?

Comment: I have tried your solutions

Comment: Please help me! I can`t post because of this topic