# WPF app not releasing memory or has memory leak

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, memory, memory-leaks

I have developed an application for a restaurant. It's a sales management system. The problem is, its not releasing memory after order completion.

The Sales page design is under tabcontrol. Submitting sales order in first tab and after submitting order, its opening another tab for taking payment. After that its printing receipt.

By submitting many order it will increase memory more & more. After using it for two or three hours, close the app automatically because of memory usage increasing.

I have used MySql as database.

Finalize the sales order, storing sales details & payment details into database with the give code bellow :

```
    /// //// Add sales item  ////////////Store into sales_item table //////////         
    public bool sales_item(string salesdate)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ((DataView)dgrvSalesItemList.ItemsSource).ToTable();
        int rows = dgrvSalesItemList.Items.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            //string SalesDate = dtSalesDate.Text;
            string trno = txtInvoice.Text;
            string itemid = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();  //dgrvSalesItemList.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            string itNam = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(); // dt.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            double qty = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());
            double Rprice = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
            double total = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][3].ToString());
            double dis = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][7].ToString()); //discount rate
            double taxapply = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][8].ToString());
            int kitchendisplay = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][9].ToString());
            string notes = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[10].ToString();


            // =================================Start=====  Profit calculation =============== Start ========= 
            // Discount_amount = (Retail_price * discount) / 100                    -- 49 * 3 / 100 = 1.47
            // Retail_priceAfterDiscount = Retail_price - Discount_amount           -- 49 - 1.47 = 47.53
            // Profit = (Retail_priceAfterDiscount * QTY )   - (cost_price * qty);  ---( 47.53 * 1 ) - ( 45 * 1) = 2.53

            string sqlprofit = "Select cost_price , discount  from  purchase  where product_id  = '" + itemid + "'";
            DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlprofit);
            DataTable dt1 = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlprofit);

            double cost_price = Convert.ToDouble(dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
            double discount = Convert.ToDouble(dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString());

            double Discount_amount = (Rprice * discount) / 100.00;
            double Retail_priceAfterDiscount = Rprice - Discount_amount;
            double Profit = Math.Round((Retail_priceAfterDiscount - cost_price), 2); // old calculation (Retail_priceAfterDiscount * qty) - (cost_price * qty);
            // =================================Start=====  Profit calculation =============== Start =========  

            string ordertime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

            string sql1 = " insert into sales_item (sales_id,itemName,Qty,RetailsPrice,Total, profit,sales_time, itemcode , discount, taxapply, note, status, ordertime) " +
                          " values ('" + trno + "', '" + itNam + "', '" + qty + "', '" + Rprice + "', '" + total + "', '" + Profit + "', " +
                          " '" + salesdate + "', '" + itemid + "', '" + dis + "', '" + taxapply + "', '" + notes + "', '" + kitchendisplay + "', '" + ordertime + "')";
            DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sql1);

            //update quantity Decrease from Stock Qty |  purchase Table
            if (txtInvoice.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please check sales no ");
            }
            else
            {

                string itemids = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString();
                double qtyupdate = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());

                // Update Quantity
                string sqlupdateQty = "select product_quantity  from purchase where product_id = '" + itemids + "'";
                DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlupdateQty);
                DataTable dtUqty = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlupdateQty);
                double product_quantity = Convert.ToDouble(dtUqty.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString()) - qtyupdate;

                string sql = " update purchase set " +
                                " product_quantity = '" + product_quantity + "' " +
                                " where product_id = '" + itemids + "' ";
                DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sql);
            }

        }
        return true;

    }

    /// //// Payment items Add  ///////////Store into Sales_payment table //////// 
    public void payment_item(string payamount, string changeamount, string dueamount, string salestype, string salesdate, string custid, string Comment)
    {
        string trno = txtInvoice.Text;
        //string payamount = lblTotalPayable.Text;
       // string changeamount = txtChangeAmount.Text;
      //  string due = txtDueAmount.Text;
        string vat = lblTotalVAT.Text;
        string DiscountTotal = lbloveralldiscount.Text; //lblTotalDisCount.Text;
       // string Comment = txtCustName.Text + " " + txtcomment.Text;
        string overalldisRate = txtDiscountRate.Text;
        string vatRate = txtVATRate.Text;
        string ordertime = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        string tableno = lblTableNo.Text;
        string tokenno = txttokenno.Text;

        string sql = "select MAX(sales_id) + 1 as sales_id from sales_payment";
        DataTable dtsales_id = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sql);

        double sales_id = Convert.ToDouble(dtsales_id.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());

        //MessageBox.Show("Sales Id = " + sales_id);

        string sql1 = " insert into sales_payment (sales_id, payment_type, payment_amount, change_amount, due_amount, dis, vat, " +
                        " sales_time, c_id, emp_id, comment, TrxType, Shopid , ovdisrate , vaterate, ordertime , tableno, tokenno ) " +
                        "  values ('" + sales_id + "','" + salestype + "', '" + payamount + "', '" + changeamount + "', " +
                        " '" + dueamount + "', '" + DiscountTotal + "', '" + vat + "', '" + salesdate + "', '" + custid + "', " +
                        " '" +  UserInfo.UserName + "','" + Comment + "','POS', '"+ UserInfo.Shopid +"', '" + overalldisRate + "' , '" + vatRate + "', " +
                        " '" + ordertime + "', '" + tableno + "', '" + tokenno + "' )";
        DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sql1);
    }

    /// //// Token no Add  ///////////Store into tbl_tokenno table //////// 
    public void tokennoInsert()
    {
        string trno = txtInvoice.Text;
        string payamount = lblTotalPayable.Text;
        string tokenno = txttokenno.Text;

        string sqltkn = " insert into tbl_tokenno (sales_id, tokenno, sales_date) " +
                        "  values ('" + txtInvoice.Text + "','" + tokenno + "',   '" + dtSalesDate.Text + "' )";
        DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqltkn);
    }
```

Printing receipt with the code given bellow :

```
    //Sale and print
    private void btnCompleteSalesAndPrint_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtPaidAmount.Text == "00" || txtPaidAmount.Text == "0" || txtPaidAmount.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            //  MessageBox.Show("Please insert paid amount", "Yes or No", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            growlNotifications.AddNotification(new Notification { Title = "Alert Message", Message = "Please insert paid amount", ImageUrl = "pack://application:,,,/Notifications/Radiation_warning_symbol.png" });
            txtPaidAmount.Focus();
        } 
        else
        {
            try
            { 
                {
                    ////Save payment info into sales_payment table
                    payment_item(lblTotalPayable.Text, txtChangeAmount.Text, txtDueAmount.Text, CombPayby.Text, dtSalesDate.Text, lblCustID.Text, txtcomment.Text);

                    // save sales items one by one  
                    sales_item(dtSalesDate.Text);

                    //// TokennoInsert
                    tokennoInsert();

                    // Open Print Invoice
                    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    parameter.autoprint = "1";
                    Sales_Register.ReceiptPrint go = new Sales_Register.ReceiptPrint(txtInvoice.Text); 
                    {
                        string sqlinfo = "select sales_id,  sales_time, ordertime, tableno, tokenno  from sales_payment  where  sales_id = '" + txtInvoice.Text + "' ";
                        DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlinfo);
                        DataTable dtinfo = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlinfo);

                        Grid Layout = new Grid();
                        Layout.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                        Layout.Width = 280;
                        Layout.Height = 677;
                        Layout.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                        RowDefinition ro1 = new RowDefinition();
                        RowDefinition ro2 = new RowDefinition();
                        ro1.Height = GridLength.Auto;

                        Layout.RowDefinitions.Add(ro1);
                        Layout.RowDefinitions.Add(ro2);
                        TextBlock ticketName = new TextBlock();
                        ticketName.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        ticketName.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                        ticketName.FontSize = 14;
                        ticketName.Text = "Ticket  : " + dtinfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[4].ToString();
                        ticketName.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        Grid.SetRow(ticketName, 0);
                        Layout.Children.Add(ticketName);

                        TextBlock Datetext = new TextBlock();
                        Datetext.Margin = new Thickness(20, 20, 0, 0); 
                        Datetext.Text = "Date : "+ dtinfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString(); 
                        Grid.SetRow(Datetext, 0);

                        Layout.Children.Add(Datetext); 
                        TextBlock timelabel = new TextBlock();
                        timelabel.Margin = new Thickness(20, 40, 0, 0);  
                        timelabel.Text = "Time : " + dtinfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[2].ToString(); 
                        Grid.SetRow(timelabel, 0);

                        Layout.Children.Add(timelabel);

                        TextBlock tablenom = new TextBlock();
                        tablenom.Margin = new Thickness(20, 60, 0, 0); 
                        tablenom.FontSize = 14;
                        tablenom.Text = "Table : " + dtinfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[3].ToString(); 
                        Grid.SetRow(tablenom, 0);

                        Layout.Children.Add(tablenom);

                        TextBlock Invoiceno = new TextBlock();
                        Invoiceno.Margin = new Thickness(20, 80, 0, 0);
                        Invoiceno.FontSize = 14;
                        Invoiceno.Text = " Invoice no: " + dtinfo.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                        Grid.SetRow(Invoiceno, 0);

                        Layout.Children.Add(Invoiceno);

                        TextBlock dash = new TextBlock();
                        dash.Margin = new Thickness(0, 110, 0, 0);
                        dash.FontSize = 14;
                        dash.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                        dash.Text = " ----------------------------- ";
                        dash.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        Grid.SetRow(dash, 0);
                        Layout.Children.Add(dash);

                        System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog Printdlg2 = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();

                        string sqlTikitem = "  select  CONCAT('- ', Qty, ' ', itemName) as 'Items'    from sales_item   where sales_id = '" + txtInvoice.Text + "' ";
                        DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sqlTikitem);
                        DataTable dtTikitem = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sqlTikitem);

                        DataGrid dt11 = new DataGrid();
                        dt11.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                        dt11.FontWeight = FontWeights.SemiBold;
                        dt11.Width = 230;
                        dt11.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
                        dt11.FontSize = 16;

                        dt11.CanUserSortColumns = false;
                        dt11.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        dt11.CanUserAddRows = false;
                        dt11.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.None;
                        dt11.HeadersVisibility = DataGridHeadersVisibility.None;

                        dt11.ItemsSource = dtTikitem.DefaultView;
                        Grid.SetRow(dt11, 1);
                        Layout.Children.Add(dt11);
                        Size pageSize2 = new Size(Printdlg2.PrintableAreaWidth, Printdlg2.PrintableAreaHeight);
                        // Size pageSize = new Size(340, 194);
                        // sizing of the element.
                        Layout.Measure(pageSize2);
                        Layout.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, pageSize2.Width, pageSize2.Height));
                        Printdlg2.MaxPage = 10;
                       Layout.UpdateLayout();
                        Printdlg2.PrintVisual(Layout, "Ticket_Print_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss"));
                    }

                    System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog Printdlg = new System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog();                       
                    {
                        Size pageSize = new Size(Printdlg.PrintableAreaWidth, Printdlg.PrintableAreaHeight);
                        go.grdPrintPanel.Measure(pageSize);
                        go.grdPrintPanel.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, pageSize.Width, pageSize.Height));
                        Printdlg.MaxPage = 10;
                        go.grdPrintPanel.UpdateLayout();
                        Printdlg.PrintVisual(go.grdPrintPanel, "C_Receipt_Print_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss"));
                    }

                    tabPayment.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    t.Rows.Clear();
                    DiscountCalculation();
                    vatcal();
                    txtbarcodescan.Focus();

                    Sales_Register.SalesRegister goSalesPage = new Sales_Register.SalesRegister();
                    goSalesPage.Show();

                    growlNotifications.AddNotification(new Notification { Title = "Wow ", Message = "Transaction has been successfully done", ImageUrl = "pack://application:,,,/Notifications/notification-icon.png" });

                }

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

I have tested for memory leak by using ReSharper dotMemory but I couldn't understand it properly.

Comment: [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433197/what-exactly-are-unmanaged-resources)

Comment: Visual Studio has a profiler built in to help find these things.

Comment: There is so much [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) in that code... please use parameterized queries.

Comment: didn't get any luck......still stuck on it.

Comment: Use memory profiler to find out what causes the problem