# How to fix CA2000 code analysis error on new DataTable instance

Tags: .net

How to fix CA2000 code analysis error in following function on statement DataTable dtSummary = new DataTable("Summary");? CA2000 going off If I use using block on dtSummary and I can't use using block in below function becuase some other function is going to use return datatable from GetSummaryReportTable function.

private DataTable GetSummaryReportTable(IImportResult result) {

```
DataTable dtSummary = new DataTable("Summary");
dtSummary.Columns.Add(STATUS_STRING_COL_NAME, typeof(string));
dtSummary.Columns.Add(STATUS_COL_NAME, typeof(int));
DataRow dataRow;

foreach (ReportErrorLevel error in distinctErrors)
{
    dataRow = dtSummary.NewRow();
    dataRow[STATUS_STRING_COL_NAME] = error.ToString();
    dataRow[STATUS_COL_NAME] = Convert.ToInt16(error);
    dtSummary.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}           
return dtSummary;
```

}

Comment: Please format your code selecting it and the using the 101010 button. It is unreadable this way...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I Dispose() DataSet and DataTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)

Answer (score 2):

This is topic has been discussed thoroughly here: [Should I Dispose() DataSet and DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable).

In short, if you really want to follow the style cop rules then you can't use DataTable as a return type. You must use some other object to return your data and wrap the DataTable object in a using statement.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535110/ca2000-false-positive#details

Using the example...

```
Private Function GetNewStream() As StreamWriter

    m_CurrentFileName = GetNewFileName()

    // Triggers CA2000
    Return New StreamWriter(New FileStream(m_CurrentFileName, _
        FileMode.Append, _
        FileAccess.Write, _
        FileShare.Read))

End Function
```

Microsoft says:

> "The reason why the rule is firing is because if StreamWriter's
>   constructor throws an exception, then the newly created FileStream
>   object is not getting disposed. **You can fix this by wrapping it in a
>   try/finally block and dispose the FileStream object in the finally
>   block only if the StreamWriter block was not created successfully.**"

That seems like a superior way to resolve the warning.