# Datatable inside using?

Tags: c#, datatable, dispose

I have declared datatable inside using block which calls the Dispose method at the end of the scope.

```
 using (DataTable dt = Admin_User_Functions.Admin_KitItems_GetItems())
            {
                 ...
            }
```

But in reflector,  datatable doesnt seens to have `Dispose` function

[image]

How is that ?

Comment: By the way, check out this <http://stackoverflow.com/a/913286/685760>

Comment: Reflector shows the methods. You can toggle "Inherited Members" (Ctrl+I) to show or hide the methods.

Comment: Reflector > Tools > Options > Browser > Check "Show inherited members".

Comment: @AMissico Didnt know that. thanks. but it shows it only in the tree on thel left and not in the disassembler on the right.

Comment: @RoyiNamir; True. It does that because the class has no implementation. If you "drill-through" in the tree pane, it will take you to the inherited class's disassembled code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Data.DataTable` extends `System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent` and, MarshalByValueComponent implements `IDisposable`.

Reflector would not display the methods of the base type unless they are overriden in the derived type.

Comment: Reflector shows the methods. You can toggle "Inherited Members" (Ctrl+I) to show or hide the methods.

Answer (score 3):

`DataTable` inherited from `MarshalByValueComponent` class  which implements `IDisposable` interface (see below), C# allows calling base class public methods for the instances of derived classes.

```
public class DataTable : MarshalByValueComponent, 
    IListSource, ISupportInitializeNotification, 
    ISupportInitialize, ISerializable, IXmlSerializable

public class MarshalByValueComponent : 
    IComponent, IDisposable, IServiceProvider
```

Your code block would be represented under the hood as shown below, so it guarantee that Dispose() method will be called:

```
{
  DataTable dt = Admin_User_Functions.Admin_KitItems_GetItems()

  try
  {
     // .. code inside using statement
  }
  finally
  {
    if (dt != null)
      ((IDisposable)dt).Dispose();
  }
}
```

See MSDN for more details: [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to dispose of the DataTable? You should delete it from its DataSet if you really want this to happen.