# disposing of old dataset and refilling it with new entries with C#

Tags: c#, dataset, reload

I have a method which returns **DataSet** from postgressql database.

```
    ds = stats.loadStats();
```

I need to update DataSet randomly, once in 3 minutes (for example).

```
                Random r = new Random();
                var rendom_number = r.Next(0, 179);//3 minutes = 3*60 = 180 sec.
                if (rendom_number == 1)
                {
                   //reload Dataset here
                }
```

**once event is triggered - I need to dispose of the old Dataset and update it with the new one, without causing overloads, memory leaks, or other troubles. How do you do it with C#?**

there are three methods that I know of, but which is the best?

1. method

   ```
           ds.Clear(); //disposing of old DataSet
           ds = stats.loadStats(); //loading new
   ```
2. method

   ```
           ds.Dispose(); //disposing of old DataSet
           ds = stats.loadStats(); //loading new
   ```
3. method

   ```
           ds = null; //disposing of old DataSet
           ds = stats.loadStats(); //loading new
   ```
4. what's your method? (or the best option)

Comment: Here is a very comprehensive review [(question and answer)][1] of possible alternatives:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is

```
//ds.Clear(); 
//ds = null; 
ds.Dispose();  // not really needed but out of general principle
ds = stats.loadStats();  // gets a new instance
```

Leave the rest to the Garbage Collector.