# No data appear on my datagridview when using dataset in c#, what am i missing here?

Tags: c#

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select sur_accounttype from tsys_user",conSQL ) ;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds,"tsys_user");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
ds.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `DataMember` property.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember="tsys_user";
```

Or create a *DataTable* and populate it.

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Remove this from your code</strike>

`ds.Dispose();`

ds.Dispose actually [doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable). The problem is with specifying the datasource to a table in the dataset.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: @odlanyer, try `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]`

Comment: Yups it makes a [no difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)

Comment: @habib, tnx for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: @V4Vendetta, thanks, your link is something totally new to me , thanks again

Comment: @Habib Actually your answer made me ponder why would it be an issue and SO didn't disappoint me, guess we both learned something good :)

Answer (score 0):

You are disposing your dataset right after you have added it to your grid