# Using Statements in DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, using

In my below function...I want to return DataTable..

Should I convert the below line

`DataTable table = CreateTable<T>();`

to following

```
using(DataTable table = CreateTable<T>())
{
}
```

### Function

```
public static DataTable ConvertTo<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    DataTable table = CreateTable<T>();

    int iColCount = table.Columns.Count;
    for (int j = 0; j < iColCount; j++)
    {
        DataColumn myDC = table.Columns[j];
        myDC.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    }

    Type entityType = typeof(T);
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entityType);
    foreach (T item in list)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        {
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item);
        } table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you?

```
using (obj)
{
    // Do something
}
```

is basically the same as:

```
try
{
    // Do something
}
finally
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```

The point is to free the resources used by your object once you don't need it anymore. In your case, you're returning the datatable to the calling function, so you're still going to need it. Therefore, there's no reason to wrap your function inside of a `using` statement.

Comment: I want to return the object also. It should be return before disposing or after disposing ?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is: you should not return a disposed object. So if you're going to return it, don't dispose it.

Comment: Ur code is disposing in Finally block. can you explain it more in details plz ?

Comment: My code is just the translation of what `using` does. I'm trying to explain that the `using` keyword is equivalent to calling the `Dispose` method inside of a finally block. Now, since you're returning your object, you mustn't call the `Dispose` method. Therefore, you mustn't use the `using` keyword either.

Answer (score 0):

The **using** statement ensures that **Dispose** is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. If you want to use **using** ask this question "Is the object disposable?". If it is then **using** is the best option. 
You might wanna try to read more on this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use using inside `ConvertTo<T>(IList<T> list)`, but caller of `ConvertTo<T>(IList<T> list)` is responsible for disposing that DataTable.

```
using (var table = Test.ConvertTo(testList)) 
{
   // do stuff with DataTable
}
```

edit: from other side, there's this post, which states that in DataTable there's nothing to dispose even if it implements IDisposable: [Should I Dispose() DataSet and DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

note that:

> The using statement calls the **Dispose** method on the object and causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called.

and `Dispose` releases all resources used by the `DataTable`.

so that you can not use [`using Statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) and returning `DataTable` object in same time.

```
public static DataTable ConvertTo<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    DataTable resultTable = CreateTable<T>();

    using(DataTable table = CreateTable<T>())
    {
         ....
         resultTable = table;
    }

    // 'table' object disposed already
    return resultTable ;
}
```

Comment: Does it make sense to return that object that is already disposed ?