# Out of memory exception while moving CSV data (3 million data) into DataTable using c#

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have 3 million rows and 40 columns of CSV file. I would like to move CSV data into SQL server using SqlBulkCopy concept. For that I moved each column and rows into data table using CSV reader. While inserting rows in data table using while loop, I am getting the memory exception. 
Note:  438184 (i value of below sample) record inserted successfully. After that I got memory exception.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
        SqlCmd.Connection = con;
SqlTransaction transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
        var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
        CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(streamReader);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        reader.ReadHeaderRecord();
        foreach (var c in reader.HeaderRecord)
        {
            table.Columns.Add(c);
        }
        table.Rows.Clear();

        int i = 0;

        while (reader.HasMoreRecords)
        {

          DataRecord record = reader.ReadDataRecord();
          table.Rows.Add(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6], record[7], record[8], record[9], record[10], record[11], record[12], record[13], record[14], record[15], record[16], record[17], record[18], record[19], record[20], record[21], record[22], record[23], record[24], record[25], record[26], record[27], record[28], record[29], record[30], record[31], record[32], record[33], record[34], record[35], record[36], record[37], record[38], record[39]);              
            i++;
        }
        SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
        copy.DestinationTableName = "SampleCSV";
        copy.WriteToServer(table);
        transaction.Commit();
            con.Close();
```

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: Do it in chunks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql bulk copy memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819151/sql-bulk-copy-memory-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you get a Memory Exception that means you cannot load all rows in a DataTable at once. You will need to execute a SqlBulkCopy every `X` row and clear the `DataTable` before processing more.

By example, the following code will execute the SqlBulkCopy every 100,000 rows loaded in the `DataTable` then clear all rows before loading more.

```
int i = 0;

while (reader.HasMoreRecords)
{
    // INSERT rows every x
    if(i % 100000 == 0)
    {
        ExecuteBulkCopy(conn, transaction, table);
        table.Rows.Clear();
    }

    DataRecord record = reader.ReadDataRecord();
    table.Rows.Add(record[0], record[1], record[2], record[3], record[4], record[5], record[6], record[7], record[8], record[9], record[10], record[11], record[12], record[13], record[14], record[15], record[16], record[17], record[18], record[19], record[20], record[21], record[22], record[23], record[24], record[25], record[26], record[27], record[28], record[29], record[30], record[31], record[32], record[33], record[34], record[35], record[36], record[37], record[38], record[39]);              
    i++;
}
// INSERT remaining row
if(table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ExecuteBulkCopy(conn, transaction, table);
}

public void ExecuteBulkCopy(SqlConnection con, SqlTransaction transaction, DataTable table)
{
    SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
    copy.DestinationTableName = "SampleCSV";
    copy.WriteToServer(table);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

**EDIT:** Answer sub-question

> Can I reduce this time if I use Bulk insert or any other?

`SqlBulkCopy` is the fastest way to insert. Even my library [.NET Bulk Operations](http://bulk-operations.net/) use SqlBulkCopy under the hood.

20 minutes for 3 million data is very slow, but it can also be normal depending on your table (char column, trigger, index, etc.)

Here are two configurations to add that will have the most impact on performance.

#### Use a BatchSize

By example 5000
It's often faster to insert multiple times with smaller batch than a VERY big batch.

#### Use TableLock options

`new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock))`
By locking the table, the SqlBulkCopy will perform faster.

Comment: Using SqlBulkCopy, it takes 20 minutes to move 3 million data (1.08 GB) into SQL server. Can I reduce this time if I use Bulk insert or any other?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Batch size

See more details for SqlBulkCopy.BatchSize Property

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.batchsize(v=vs.110).aspx

alternatively if your destination table schema is fixed then you can make use of SSIS package.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
   //you can define any Banch of Data insert
   copy.BatchSize(10000);
   copy.DestinationTableName = "SampleCSV";
   copy.WriteToServer(table);
   transaction.Commit();
   con.Close();
```

Comment: I am getting the memory exception while executing 'while loop'. It was thrown before executing 'SqlBulkCopy' code. So my problem was not resolved. Can you please suggest me another solution?