# Getting an error while invoking bytes from database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have stored an image in SQL Server. First I have converted the image into bytes and I have saved it in SQL Server and very much done with saving.....when I try to invoke the respective image's bytes value from SQL Server which I saved and when I try to implement that in C#, I am getting a error like

> *NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code*
>
> *Object Reference not set to an instance of an object*

Here is my code:

```
protected void GetImageButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();  
    connection.ConnectionString = @"";  
    connection.Open();  
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();  
    command.Connection = connection;  
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
    command.CommandText = "uspgetimage";  
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imageID", getimagebutton.Text);  
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();  
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();  
    adapter.SelectCommand = command;  
    adapter.Fill(dataset);  
    Byte[] bytes = command.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];  
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);  
    Image.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;  
}
```

Kindly have a look on it and help me to get out from this friends.

Comment: This question, the edit by Soner Gonul seems very very familiar. I had like 10 Deja-Vus right now. Tell me if you have asked this question before?

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net Debug your code and find which line throws this _exception_ and fix it. Probably one of your variable is `null` and you try to use before you initialize it.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? or better post your stored procedure..Probably this part is return null: `Byte[] bytes = command.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];`

Comment: yeah thank u friends :) error was in the line Byte[] bytes = command.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];...error with the procedure returning the value.....now i got the answer.....thanks a lot for your help friends :)

Comment: Great..can you post your stored procedure? and make sure there is row with id = `imageID`.

Answer (score 0):

Before *NullReferanceException*, I don't believe this lines *don't* throw any exception..

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();  
connection.ConnectionString = @"";  
connection.Open();
```

You can't open a connection before you initialize `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` property. In your case, your connection string is an *empty string*. How do you expect this connection connect to your sql server?

My suggestion is, read a book about C# and using it with databases like *[Begining C# 5.0 Databases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242604)*

For *NullReferanceException*, I already mentioned in my *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459141/getting-an-error-while-invoking-bytes-from-sql-server-and-implementing-in-c-shar#comment21874403_15459141)* what you should do.

Comment: Imho, I think the OP want to hide his connection string...:)

Comment: i just hidden my connection...btw,its working fine now...problem was with procedure only...thanks a lot for your help friends :)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're getting a `NullReferenceException` from your call to `ExecuteScalar`. From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

> ## Return Value
>
> The first column of the first row in the result set, **or a null reference ... if the result set is empty**.

Emphasis mine.

And for what it's worth, `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `DataSet` and `SqlDataAdapter` are all `IDisposable`. You should call `Dispose` on them, although [the value of disposing `DataSet` is arguable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable).

Comment: the problem was with procedure only...i cleared it and now the error got done ..... thanks a lot for your help friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the stored procedure in SQL Server to see if it returns any value using

```
EXEC uspgetimage 'COmma seperated Parameter List'
```