# Finally and c# reference types

Tags: c#

I am not able to figure how will this work:

```
public Class1 Function1()
{
   DataTable dt;
   try
   {
     dt = new DataTable();
     //.. Do some work
     return new Class2(byref dt);
   }
   finally
   {
      dt.dispose();
   }
}


public Class2(byref DataTable dTable)
{
    this.dataTable = dTable;
}
```

So, now if I say `Class1 obj1 = Function1();` will my `obj1.dataTable` be disposed? or it will have proper data?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable

Comment: @Yogesh - Yes it would be disposed because you call `DataTable.Dispose()` and you pass the `DataTable` as a reference.

Comment: Technically you should declare and initialize `dt` outside of the `try` block.  If the construction fails, you don't want to dispose it, and if it doesn't fail, there's no reason to surround that line in the `try/finally`.  (also this is why `using` exists)

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, the link you posted was really resourceful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes assuming `obj1.dataTable` refers to the same object  you created inside `Function1`, it will have been disposed. `Finally` blocks are always executed, regardless of whether an exception is thrown or not.

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zwc8s4fz.aspx) some more information on try-finally blocks.