# Windows Forms application memory leak .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory-leaks

There is a winforms application, where couple of forms are very complicated - using datasets, multiple bindings with grids and comboboxes..
Every time when I open the form, the memory usage grows for about 2-5 MB until I get OutOfMemoryException.
I use `using` statements for every `IDisposable` (for `Form`s too), tried to clear all the bindings and unsubscribe my events within Dispose(), nothing changed.
If I call `GC.Collect()` after disposing the form, used memory amount returns in previous state, as it was before opening the form.
I have tried some memory profilers, but they did not show anything extraordinary.

Comment: Are you caching data?

Comment: have you tried taking snap-shots in the profilers to see what is the resource that isn't cleared? that might give you a direction

Comment: I think that I am not caching any data..
I have been taking memory snap-shots and analyzing them for a week and  did not found anything that could indicate a memory leak.

Comment: How much data are you loading when opening the form?

Comment: between snapshots do you see difference in memory? in what parts of it? surely if you get out of memory exception that should be reflected in the snapshots (possibly in unmanaged resources).

Comment: If you are hitting an out of memory exception, and you've profiled it, what *is* in memory according to the profiles?  Extraordinary or not, there must be a lot of *something* in there...

Comment: You are using a lot of unmanaged code, wrapped by thin .NET wrapper classes.  Not getting the garbage collector to run often enough is certainly possible.  .NET memory profilers are not very good at tracking unmanaged memory usage.  The workaround for not being able to find a missing Dispose() call and not getting GCs to keep you out of trouble is calling GC.Collect().  Pretty reasonable after looking for a week and not getting anywhere.

Comment: As you are not asking anything i would suggest you to read the FAQ on how to write a good question. Anyway, i think nobody can help you to fix your memory leak only by guessing.

Comment: If the data is coming from a database, switch on profiling and measure the amount of data. You can GC.Collect whatever you want but if you are loading a gazillion rows....

Comment: All I can say is that you use too much time trying "some memory profilers" instead of fully understanding one of them. If you can tell yourself clearly why there are many objects on the heap, and whether some of them indicate problems, this is never a complicated case. If you are not capable of troubleshooting, consider opening a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and consult Microsoft, or resort to the profiler vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Because the memory grows so rapidly, the problem must be in the Paint method of one of the controls (if you paint/draw the control yourself) or in the auto-update loop of your grids (if you update the data source periodically).

1. Check if you dispose all Brushes, Pens, Font, StringFormats in your paint loop.
2. Check the update-loop of your data sources. Common errors are SqlCommand and SqlConnections which are not disposed properly.

Hope this helps. Without more detailed information about your source-code it's hard to provide any other help.

Comment: I think those are sound advices. However the OP said he did do all those things. Therfor I think that memory profiler is the way to go. If it does not show results it must not have been used effectively.

Comment: Every developer thinks he used IDisposable everywhere. But especially in painting/drawing you easily miss some. But you are right, you will find the problem using a profiler like NetMemoryProviler, CLRProfiler or Yourkit .NET Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your `DataSet` is not released correctly although you dispose it.
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Note: Classes inherited from DataSet are not finalized by the garbage
>   collector, because the finalizer has been suppressed in DataSet. The
>   derived class can call the [ReRegisterForFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.reregisterforfinalize%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method in its
>   constructor to allow the class to be finalized by the garbage
>   collector.

And you should read this question that can be very usefull [Should I Dispose() DataSet and DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)

Answer (score 1):

My employer, Red Gate Software, makes a .NET memory profiling tool you could use to investigate your problem. It has a 14-day trial which might be long enough to find your leak for free :)

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

There is also 'dotTrace Memory' by jetBRAINS, although I've not tried it.