# How to cache a DataSet and NOT receive the CA2000 warning

Tags: asp.net, caching, dataset, dispose, ca2000

I have a DataSet that I would like to cache in the ASP.NET's web cache.  The content does not change very often and a cache of a few hours should work.

My problem is that when I create the DataSet, I get a CA2000 warning about dispose needing to be called.  However, some articles say that I can cache the DataSet.  I don't believe the DataSet directly implements Dispose; however, it is derived from a class that does.

What is the best way to cache a DataSet so I do not receive the CA2000 warning?

Comment: Indeed, you don't need to dispose a DataSet in the general case. Post your code.

Comment: I would really like to see an answer to this; I have some legacy code which has a DAL based on Enterprise Library that slings DataSets around like they are going out of fashion; these DataSets work their way back up to the UI (an ASP.NET application) which does not explicitly dispose them. When I run Code Analysis on the DAL looking for undisposed connection objects, data readers etc, I get literally hundreds of these almost-false-positives from the undisposed datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I do not get the same warning you are getting; but indeed, you don't need to dispose a `DataSet` in the general case as it doesn't contain any unmanaged resources.

[See this other answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)