# Will DataTable.Dispose() remove it from memory?

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose, system.data.datatable

I am confused about the effect of calling `Dispose()` on a `DataTable`. Here is my code to create and dispose a table:

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getData", SqlCon);
SqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlCon.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(dr);
SqlCon.Close();
grdView.DataSource = dt;

// Here I dispose the table as I no longer need it and want to free the memory.
dt.Dispose();
```

But after disposing of the `DataTable` I found that it is still showing RowCount = 10k.

Does the `Dispose()` method free up the memory and set the object as `null`? How can I make it `null` or free up the memory occupied by this object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I Dispose() DataSet and DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)

Comment: Note on the proposed duplicate - the accepted answer just refers to that other question...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`DataSet` and `DataTable` don't actually have any unmanaged resources, so `Dispose()` doesn't do much. The `Dispose()` methods in `DataSet` and `DataTable` exist ONLY as a side effect of inheritance - in other words, they don't actually do anything useful in the finalization.

It turns out that `DataSets`, `DataViews`, `DataTables` suppress finalization in their constructors; this is why calling `Dispose()` on them explicitly does nothing.

Presumably, this happens because, as mentioned above, they don't have unmanaged resources; so despite the fact that `MarshalByValueComponent` makes allowances for unmanaged resources, these particular implementations don’t have the need and can therefore forgo finalization.

**Overview of [this Immense Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1603516/626442):**

> Without a doubt, Dispose should be called on any Finalizable objects.
>
> DataTables are Finalizable.
>
> Calling Dispose significantly speeds up the reclaiming of memory.
>
> `MarshalByValueComponent` calls `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` in its `Dispose()` - skipping this means having to wait for dozens if not hundreds of `Gen0` collections before memory is reclaimed.

**Further Reading:**

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable) and the related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913286/626442).

Comment: Thanks bu the answer is confusing. What is the conclusion?

Comment: By all means call `Dispose()` but it doesn't do anything. Essentially, using dispise on the objects is not required.

Answer (score 9):

> Does Dispose() method does not free up the memory & make object as
>   null ??

`Dispose` and the disposal pattern is not for reclaiming managed memory or "deleting" managed objects (both things you cannot do and what the Garbage Collector is there for), it is for handling the disposal/release of unmanaged resources or other managed resources that have releasable items, such as `SqlConnection`. It *certainly* won't `null` the reference, but may make it unusable from the time of disposal forwards.

> How can i make it as null or free up the memory occupied by this
>   object ??

If you want to null the reference, simply `dt = null` will work, though this **will not** give you any benefit as the `DataTable` instance is referenced by `grdView.DataSource`. Both `dt` and `grdView.DataSource` will be references to the same underlying `DataTable` instance.

I also suspect this is part of a method in which case `dt` is method-scoped anyway.

You shouldn't have to worry too much about any of this stuff. I'd be more concerned about having the `SqlConnection` outside of a `try-finally` / `using`, you are at risk of leaving a connection open there.

I tend to favour calling `Dispose` on items that implement `IDisposable` for what I think is a *very* good reason: this is the **public contract**. The fact of whether calling it does anything or not is an **implementation detail** and is **liable to change** at a moments notice.

---

As an aside, I would completely re-write your code:

```
var dt = new Datatable();

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(""))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand("sp_getData", conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dt.Load(reader);
    }
}

grdView.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: If i make it dt=null, gridview still doing well.. Does it good habit to make it null and free up memory ??

Comment: @Rajeev I think it's a good habit to call `Dispose` on items that you are finished with, however, you have assigned the `DataTable` to the `DataSource`, so you don't want to call `Dispose` as it isn't finished with. Explicitly nulling items is rarely ever needed.

Comment: I am not asking about calling Dispose() method instead of making it as null by calling `dt = null`. Gridview still doing well in this case and my memory is also get freeup

Comment: @RajeevKumar You have only freed up a single reference (4 or 8 bytes), the underlying 10k rows are still there in the `grdView.DataSource` property. By all means `null` if you are finished with it, but I am just saying that I very rarely have to explicitly do that.

Comment: I am trying to find the solutions because my application crash after some period of time saying `system.outofmemory` Exception

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Clear() function. It works great for me for disposing.

```
DataTable dt = GetDataSchema();
//populate dt, do whatever...
dt.Clear();
```