# Dispose datatable object which i need to return from my method

Tags: c#, datatable, dispose

```
DataTable dt= new Datatable();
try {
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getData",SqlCon);
    SqlCommand.CommandType= CommandType.StroedProcedure;
    SqlCon.Open();
    sqlDataReader dr=  cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt.Load(dr);
    SqlCon.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
}
finally{
    dt.Dispose() //
}

return dt;
```

Is this code legitimate ?... My method is returning that datatable object , so after calling dispose will that retain the value ??.. please explain..

Comment: Did you try to get as many problems as possible in that piece of code?  Please read up on `IDisposable` and `using blocks`. You are leaving your locals undisposed and you dispose the only thing you are returning.

Comment: anyone out der ??.. Please pour in your seuggestions....

Comment: This is not legitimate. See this pose - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869079/datatable-dispose-will-make-it-remove-from-memory

Comment: Do one more change! Put your SqlCon.Close() inside the finally, because if you get some error for example with the ExecuteReader, your connection will not close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will give you what you want:

```
    public DataTable getDataTable()
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getData", sqlCon))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCon.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

No. You will be returning an already-disposed object.

If you are returning an `IDisposable` it is perfectly normal to expect it to be the caller's responsibility to dispose of the object when they are through with it. Therefore, you should return the `DataTable` object as is, undisposed, and let the calling code dispose of it.

Normally this would be done with a using block. For example:

```
class MyDisposableObject : IDisposable { /*...*/ }

public MyDisposableObject MakeMeAnObject() { return new MyDisposableObject(); }

public void Main()
{
    using(var o = MakeMeAnObject())
    {
        o.Foo = 1;
        o.Bar = 2;
        o.FooBar();
    }
}
```

---

*Note I do see some local `IDisposable` objects in your snippet that you are not disposing but should be. You are also swallowing exceptions.*

Answer (score 1):

This will return a disposed object which isn't what you want.

One thing you can do is pass a delegate, which will allow you to work on the DataTablr without returning it, and still dispose within your original data method.

Pseudo-code:

```
public void GetSomeData(Action<DataTable> processDataTableAction)
{
    try
    { 
        ... ( get the data )
        processDataTableAction(dt);
    }
    catch
    {
        // handle exceptions
    }
    finally
    {
        dt.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then to call the function elsewhere in code:

```
GetSomeData(dt => {
    // do stuff with dt
});
```