# C# MemoryCache Resource Boundaries

Tags: c#, caching, com+, memorycache

I was wondering if the System.Runtime.Cache.MemoryCache marshals objects into a separate resource space, or if it resides in the same resource space as the calling object?

For instance, say I write a helper method, on some abstract object, that allows me to read and write objects (such as DataTables) to the cache:

```
public static void WriteCache(string KeyName, object Item, int ExpireMinutes = 30)
{
    ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

    policy.SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(0, ExpireMinutes, 0);
    policy.Priority = CacheItemPriority.Default;

    cache.Add(new CacheItem(KeyName, Item), policy);
}
```

And then send a DataTable to the cache:

```
WriteCache("MY_DATA", dt, 15);
```

Would disposing the DataTable in the calling code, afterwards, also dispose the DataTable in the Cache? Or is the DataTables copied to the Cache (like a COM+ object, in Server Mode, when it marshals across to its resource space)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that DataTable doesn't have any unmanaged resources to dispose of ([explained well in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869079/datatable-dispose-will-make-it-remove-from-memory)).

Reference types (like DataTable) are added to MemoryCache as references to the object being added. Object remains in the same resource space.

Here's a trivial POCO to illustrate the behaviour:

```
class SimpleClass
    {
        public string someText { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        var simpleObject = new SimpleClass { someText = "starting text" };
        SimpleClass cachedContent = null;

        CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

        cache.Add("mykey", simpleObject, policy);

        // Expect "starting text" output
        cachedContent = (SimpleClass) cache.Get("mykey");
        Console.WriteLine(cachedContent.someText);

        simpleObject.someText = "new text";

        // Now it will output "new text"
        cachedContent = (SimpleClass)cache.Get("mykey");
        Console.WriteLine(cachedContent.someText);

        // simpleObject points nowhere now but object still exists, 
        // pointed to by cache item so will still output "new text"
        simpleObject = null;
        cachedContent = (SimpleClass)cache.Get("mykey");
        Console.WriteLine(cachedContent.someText);
    }
```