# How to dispose of datatables by using the 'Using' statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, using

I am trying to use using statement for a data table so that it disposes off when out of scope, but inside using scope it says cannot assign datatable to a using variable. Below is the code.
Without using the 'Using statement' and by using DataTable dt = null, all works fine.

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTble())
{
 
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("DBConection"))
 {
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SPNAME", connection);
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 dt = (DataTable)cmd.ExecuteNonquery(); // here it says cannot assign to dt because it is a using variable
 }      
 
 return dt;
}
```

Comment: Does `DataTable` even Implement `IDisposable` ?

Comment: Yes, `DataTable` does implement `IDisposable` -> `DataTable : MarshalByValueComponent` & `MarshalByValueComponent : IDisposable`.

Comment: You can't return the `DataTable` as it will be disposed before it is returned to the calling code.

Comment: @Enigmativity I stand corrected. IIRC there was a time where the interfaces implemented via inheritance was documented as well, which is why I made that mistake in he first place.

Answer (score 2):

You should remember that within the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or reassigned. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: While this does help understand the error that the OP is seeing, it doesn't address the actual question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The code to posted to populate a `DataTable` seems wrong to me as `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an `int` so it can't be cast to a `DataTable` anyway.

The way I do it is to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a table.

Here's code that compiles - but ***don't use it as this is not going to work***:

```
public DataTable UsingDataTable()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("DBConection"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPNAME", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can't return a `DataTable` that you are disposing at the same time it returns. The calling code needs to be able to work with it ***before*** it is disposed.

So the way to do that is to ***inject*** the code that uses the `DataTable` into the method so that it can be executed before it returns. Try this:

```
public void UsingDataTable(Action<DataTable> action)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("DBConection"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPNAME", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    a.Fill(dt);
                    action(dt);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call that like this:

```
UsingDataTable(dt => Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for implementing the using statement on datatables,datasets.This is because datatables,datasets suppress finalization in their constructors.There is no real benefit in implementing the using statement on datatables,datasets.

Comment: Please explain this. What does "suppress finalization in their constructors" have to do with "no need for implementing the using statement"?

Answer (score -1):

as comments say, you can only use `using` statement on a `class` that implements `IDisposible` and `Datatable` doesn't do that. However, you can dispose the `DataTable` by using its own `dispose()` method. Just to make it super clear, that also isn't necessary as `DataTable` **does not have any unmanaged resources**.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869079/datatable-dispose-will-make-it-remove-from-memory) answer for details.

Comment: Yes, `DataTable` does -> `DataTable : MarshalByValueComponent` & `MarshalByValueComponent : IDisposable`.