# Code Analysis CA2000 Surpress automatically for DataTables

Tags: .net, visual-studio, datatable, code-analysis, fxcop

I work in a team environment and have been tasked with implementing code analysis.  I'm currently looking to find a good set of rules for our team, and using our current code as a model for which ones to keep and which ones to remove. CA2000 actually found issues in our code, but it also finds tons of DataTable/DataSet that aren't being disposed.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable), we don't need to dispose of them and we have a ton of code out there that doesn't dispose of them.  We don't want to spend time on changing that.

What's the shortest path to keeping the warning where relevant (all over the place sadly) and removing the noise from all the DataTables (which the team doesn't want to spend time fixing)?  I've looked into building a custom rule (which I'd rather not do), but was wondering if this was a solved problem already. I've googled, but I'm not finding anything relevant.  Any help?

Comment: No, scratch the idea of a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1603516/170864) on the question that [you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable) (which has more upvotes than the accepted answer) suggests that you should be disposing them (as they are finalizable objects).

Unfortunately this may not sway those who don't want to fix the issue, but looking to  suppress this warning may give a false sense of security and could mask future issues.