# Getting many system out of memory exceptions

Tags: c#, linq

My program reads data off of a datatable using linq queries and writes it to a local file. I have the stream and the streamwriter wrapped in using statements but I'm getting many system out of memory exceptions. Am I supposed to call the dispose method on the datatables as well in my code? That is the only solution I can think of

My code:

```
public static async void getTrainingData(string symbol, string market)
    {
        decimal returnPct = 0, shortRating = 0, rsi = 0, mfi = 0, williamsR = 0, macd = 0, sma20 = 0, sma50 = 0, sma200 = 0;
        string path = "training.csv";
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
        int count = 0;

        try
        {
            using (Calculations calc = createCalcClass(symbol, market))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 4096, FileOptions.Asynchronous))
                using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    DateTime date;

                            var amexQuery = from c in calc.dailyAmexTable.AsEnumerable()
                                            orderby c.Date descending
                                            select c;

                            count = Convert.ToInt32(calc.dailyAmexAdapter.ScalarQuerySymbol(symbol));
                            for (int i = 0; i < count - 14; i++)
                            {
                                if (i != count - 15)
                                {
                                    returnPct = calc.calculateReturnPercentage(amexQuery.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1).AdjustedClose, amexQuery.ElementAtOrDefault(i).AdjustedClose);
                                    date = amexQuery.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1).Date;

                                    if (returnPct >= 10)
                                    {
                                        calc.calculatePctGainsLosses(14, date);
                                        shortRating = calculateRating(calc, ratingType.short_rating, date);
                                        rsi = calc.calculateRSI(14, date);
                                        mfi = calc.calculateMFI(14, date);
                                        williamsR = calc.calculateWilliamsR(14, date);
                                        macd = calc.calculateMACDDivergence(date);
                                        sma20 = calc.calculateReturnPercentage(calc.calculateSMA(20, date),
                                            calc.getSpecificValues(Calculations.valueType.Most_Recent_Close, 0, date));
                                        sma50 = calc.calculateReturnPercentage(calc.calculateSMA(50, date),
                                            calc.getSpecificValues(Calculations.valueType.Most_Recent_Close, 0, date));
                                        sma200 = calc.calculateReturnPercentage(calc.calculateSMA(200, date),
                                            calc.getSpecificValues(Calculations.valueType.Most_Recent_Close, 0, date));
                                        Task write = TextWriter.Synchronized(writer).WriteLineAsync(returnPct + "," + symbol + "," + shortRating + "," +
                                            rsi + "," + mfi + "," + williamsR + "," + macd + "," + sma20 + "," + sma50 + "," + sma200);
                                        taskList.Add(write);
                                        // add the necessary info to the training data file
                                        // stock rating, pct change, rsi, mfi, williams r, macd, 20 day sma, 50 day sma, 200 day sma
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                    await writer.FlushAsync();
                }

                // wait for all tasks to complete
                Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine("Return percentages for " + symbol + " saved to training file.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Example output:

[image: example output]

Comment: In reference to your specific question about disposing datatables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable

Comment: Yes thank you I did read that article. That was the only idea that came to mind but it still seems to have that exception thrown so I am at a loss what else I could be missing in my code

Comment: Have you profiled your application to learn where the memory is going?

Comment: I actually don't know how to do that

Comment: Ok correction I did find the option in visual studio and I'm running it now but I'm not sure where you go to see where the memory leak could be

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing what all your functions are doing. You need to try and narrow the problem down.

Comment: For one thing, the `amexQuery.Count()` calls are demanding the entire list into memory at once. Admittedly it is rather difficult to return all but the last N elements of a list lazily.

Comment: You won't see memory leaks in C# easily. Just check whether there are too many objects allocated. If you are not using Ultimate edition you will likely need to dump heaps between different timestamps and diff them with something like http://thinkexception.blogspot.de/2010/06/tool-to-bompare-two-windbg-dumpheap.html

Comment: Ok I updated my above code and to show you guys what the output is. Any ideas on why I'm still getting out of memory exceptions and why the output looks like that?

Comment: Try awaiting the taskList before Flushing the writer.

Comment: Found this question while I was googling why FileMode.Append can cause OutOfMemory Exceptions. 

When I switched to FileMode.Open my OutOfMemory Exceptions were gone