# Should I reuse table adapter instances?

Tags: c#, .net, database

I currently have a class similar to the below (omited error checking)

Currently this is how the database is wrapped into easier to use objects.

I was wondering if I was going to be loading say 50,000 orders if I should be creating the table adapters once and then reusing them, instead of creating a new table adapter for each order?

I have not seen any real speed issues doing it this way. But would it be best practise to not keep creating new table adapters each time?

If so is there a pre-existing patten to handle this?

```
class Order
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public SaleLocaion SalePoint { get; set; }

    public Order(int orderId)
    {
        using (var ta = new OrdersTableAdapter())
        {
            using (var res = ta.GetDataById(orderId))
            {
                if (res.Count == 1)
                {
                    var row = res.First();
                    Id = row.Id;
                    CustomerEmail = row.Email;
                    SalePoint = new SaleLocaion(row.SaleLocationId);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



class SaleLocaion
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public SaleLocaion(int locationId)
    {
        using (var ta = new SaleLocationAdapter())
        {
            using (var res = ta.GetDataById(locationId))
            {
                if (res.Count == 1)
                {
                    var row = res.First();
                    Id = row.Id;
                    Name = row.Name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter if you reuse them or not. They implement `IDisposable` but just because they inherit from `Component` which implements `IDisposable` because of the DataSet's drag and drop capabilities. But it's not necessary to dispose them for the same reason why `DataSet` and `DataTable` implement `IDisposable` but [don't really need to be disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable).

The constructor or the field initialization are also very cheap since all fields are `null` and the constructor only contains:

```
public OrdersTableAdapter() { // an examplary auto-generated table-adapter constructor
    this.ClearBeforeFill = true;
}
```

So choose the most readable and fail-safe approach.

Comment: thanks, does that mean I could drop the using around the ta.GetDataById()?

Comment: @james: if that returns a `DataTable`, yes.