# How to Bind Data in Grid View

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/firstpage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="MasterCodes.aspx.cs" Inherits="MasterCodes" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false"
        EnablePartialRendering="false">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="contentarea">
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblsub" Style="overflow-x: auto; margin-left: 20px;" runat="server" Text="Station master data entry" />
    </div>
    <div style="overflow: auto; padding: 10px 20px;">
       <br />
       <asp:Label ID="lblcontractnumber" runat="server" Text="Station Code" Font-Names="Calibri"></asp:Label>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtcontractnumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
    <div style="overflow: auto; padding: 10px 20px;">
       <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Station Name:  " Font-Names="Calibri"></asp:Label>
       <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="3A1-Elevated" Font-Names="Calibri"></asp:Label>
   </div>
    <div style="overflow: auto; padding: 10px 20px;">
        <asp:GridView ID="grd_mastercodes" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#f79646" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
            HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" Font-Names="Calibri"
            Font-Size="Medium" RowStyle-BackColor="White" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="Black"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle-BorderColor="Black" OnRowCreated="grd_mastercodes_RowCreated">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using AjaxControlToolkit;


public partial class MasterCodes : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    bool rowset = false;
    GridView dgv = new GridView();
    // For First gridview
    String[] gridColumnNames_mastercodes = { "S.NO", "WBE Codes", "BOQ ID", "Description", "Unit", "Budgeted Quantity", "Variation Quantity", "Revised Quantity" };
    String[] gridColumnwidth_mastercodes = { "50px", "200px", "200px", "350px", "100px", "100px", "100px", "100px" };
    int[] gridColumnWidth_mastercodes = { 3, 15, 15, 45, 10, 10, 10, 10 };

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // For First gridview
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                for (int c = 0; c < gridColumnNames_mastercodes.Length; c++)
                {
                    DataColumn dcol = new DataColumn(c.ToString(), typeof(System.Int32));
                    dcol.ColumnName = gridColumnNames_mastercodes[c];
                    dt.Columns.Add(dcol);

                    TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
                    tf.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = false;
                    tf.HeaderText = gridColumnNames_mastercodes[c];
                    tf.HeaderStyle.Width = new Unit(gridColumnwidth_mastercodes[c]);
                    grd_mastercodes.Columns.Add(tf);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
                }
                grd_mastercodes.DataSource = dt;
                grd_mastercodes.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message.ToString();
            System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
        }
    }

    //For First Gridview
    protected void grd_mastercodes_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int rc = 0; rc < grd_mastercodes.Columns.Count; rc++)
                {
                    TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
                    txtBox.ID = "Excel_mastercodes" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rc;
                    txtBox.MaxLength = gridColumnWidth_mastercodes[rc];
                    txtBox.Width = new Unit(gridColumnwidth_mastercodes[rc]);
                    txtBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                    e.Row.Cells[rc].Controls.Add(txtBox);
                    e.Row.Cells[rc].Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "enter(this);");
                    if (rc == 3)
                        txtBox.Style["text-align"] = "left";
                    else
                        txtBox.Style["text-align"] = "center";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message.ToString();
            System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AlertBox", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

I need retrieve data from sql db . I know that still i din't connect to db but i am struggle where to write sql statement in above code  to retrieve data. If any one know means please help me.
Tanks

Answer (score 0):

I have an sample data for binding the gridview, You can customize accordingly

**ASPX CODE**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdhospital"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            Width="100%"
            border="1"
            AllowPaging="true"
            OnPreRender="PreRenderGrid"
            PageSize="2"
            OnDataBound="grdhospital_DataBound"
            OnPageIndexChanging="grdhospital_PageIndexChanging"
            Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;"
            CellPadding="3"
            CssClass="hoverTable"
            DataKeyNames="Id"
            OnRowCommand="grdhospital_RowCommand"
            OnRowDeleting="grdhospital_RowDeleting"
            EmptyDataText="No records found"
            ShowFooter="false"
            HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td"
            EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="k-alt" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="5">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" onClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="hospital_name" HeaderText="Hospital Name" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="5%">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" AlternateText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="eEdit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**CS DataBindCode:-**

First we need to write `BindGrid()` method like below

```
public void BindGrid()
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from yourtablename");
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    grdhospital.DataSource = dt;
                    grdhospital.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then we need to call the above method on `Page_load`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: The [general consensus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable) is that you usually don't need to use a `using` statement with a DataTable. You can probably eliminate that bit and simplify your code.

Comment: but i need my grid view as a excel sheet format which means the Text box  should like excel                                                                             "txtBox.ID = "Excel_mastercodes" + e.Row.RowIndex + "_" + rc;"