# filter using checkboxlist

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, filtering, checkboxlist

I want to filter data using two CheckBoxList, and the result must be shown in a GridView. My data is stored in SQL Server DataBase. 
I have done some code but it's not working, whene I check some boxes nothing happen. 
Here is my code

```
public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindList();
        }
    }
    protected void gvDemo_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
   {
       gvDemo.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
       BindList();
   }

   private void BindList()
   {
       string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YMMDMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
       string query = "SELECT ID,Client,Projet,Date,Shift,CodDefaut FROM cascad";
       string condition = string.Empty;
       foreach (ListItem item in shift.Items)
       {
           condition += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : "";
       }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
       {
           condition = string.Format(" where Shift in ({0})", condition.Substring(0, condition.Length - 1));
       }

       string condition2 = string.Empty;
       foreach (ListItem item in client.Items)
       {
           condition2 += item.Selected ? string.Format("'{0}',", item.Value) : "";
       }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition2))
       {
           condition2 = string.Format(" AND Client = {0}", condition2.Substring(0, condition2.Length - 1));
       }
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query + condition + condition2); 

       using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
       {
           using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
           {
               cmd.Connection = con; 
               sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
               using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
               {
                   sda.Fill(ds);
                   gvDemo.DataSource = ds;
                   gvDemo.DataBind();
               }
           }
       }
   }

   protected void shift_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       BindList();

   }

   protected void client_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       foreach (ListItem item in shift.Items)
       {
           if (item.Selected == true)
           {
               BindList();
           }
       } 
   }
```

}

What am I missing?

Comment: When you debug this - because I assume you've debugged this, of course - what is the full SQL query that you send to the server?

Comment: Why do you call `BindList` in a loop? You just need to call it once (if needed).

Comment: I have two ChechBoxList : shift & client                                                                  the full query is : query + condition + condition2 and it depend on which boxes I checked

Comment: You have add hardcode script `" AND Client = {0}"` which is causing issue if you do not select first checkbox and select the second. I would suggest you to create a stored procedure in SQL and accept two nullable parameter and handle NULL case in SQL query.

Comment: It doesn't cause anything even if I select at first the second checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

You [don't really need to dispose a `DataSet` or `DataTable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)(even if it implements `IDisposable`, it does it only for designer stuff). So the `using` is redundant. That might also cause the issue if you use the disposed `DataSet` as `DataSource`.

So just:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet())
sda.Fill(ds);
gvDemo.DataSource = ds;
gvDemo.DataBind();
```

Apart from  that, it's not clear if the created sql query is correct. Have you verified that it works in Sql-Server Management-Studio?

By the way, why do you call `BindList` in a loop? You just need to call it once (if needed). So this might be more appropriate:

```
bool needToDatabind = false;
foreach (ListItem item in shift.Items)
{
   if (item.Selected == true)
   {
       needToDatabind = true;
       break;
   }
} 
if(needToDatabind) BindList();
```

or more concise:

```
var selectedItems = shift.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected);
if(selectedItems.Any()) BindList();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but I don't think that the problem is in the loop I have tried u're code but it doesn't work. For the query I don't know how to verify it in Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: @Lamyae: set a breakpoint at `sda.SelectCommand = cmd;` and grab the sql query that you find in `cmd.CommandText`. What means it doesnt work, do you get an error?

Comment: The problem it doesn't give me any error so I can't determine where it comes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have made `AutoPostBack="true"` to your Check Box.

[image]

to add a break point just click to add break point as in image and press F5 to debug.

Hope this help?

Comment: must I add teh AutoPostBack="true" for each CheckBoxList??

Comment: are you using any update panel? have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: I don't use update panel and for sure I debug the code but it doesn't work and doesn't give me any error

Comment: put a break point at `sda.SelectCommand = cmd;` and try to see/check what is the sql query there.

Comment: I don't know how pleas explain me more

Comment: @Lamyae i need atleast 10 Reputation to post image, currently it is 8 only, so without adding an image to my answer it is difficult to explain you.

Comment: thanks sharique :) can I contact u via facebook to exchange easly images?

Comment: @Lamyae i have modified my answer.