# Do we need to close SQLite connection when exiting WP app?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

In the `App.xaml.cs` of my universal app I have opened an SQLConnection. I'm not closing the connection. So far it hasn't caused me trouble. But is it the right way, can we leave it like that?

If we are to close the connection (`Dispose()` because I don’t see a close function) where do we close? In the `App_Closing`?

**EDIT**

This is how I'm opening the connection in App.xaml.cs

```
public static SQLiteConnection conn;
public void LoadDatabase()
    {
        conn = new SQLiteConnection( "JusWriteDB.db");

        string sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Folder (FolderCompletedStatus INTEGER, FolderPriority INTEGER, PenColor INTEGER,                                                         FolderText TEXT, FolderUUID TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL );";
        using (var statement = conn.Prepare(sql))
        {
            try
            {
                statement.Step();
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

And where ever(in some other file) I need a to access this connection, to update table or insert. I access it through the public variable defined in App.xaml.cs

```
 var db = App.conn;
 string sql = "SELECT * from Folder Where FolderSyncStatus = 'Del'; ";
 try
    {
      using (var statement = db.Prepare(sql))
      {
         while (statement.Step() == SQLiteResult.ROW)
         { //  code 
         }
      }
    }
  catch{}
```

Comment: I don't know much about WP but pretty sure you should close it.

Comment: I would wrap the connection in a Using, then atleast you would be sure it closes when exiting program.

Answer (score 5):

The general rule is to always invoke `Dispose()` method on `IDisposalbe` objects. So yes, you should close it.
The next question is where.
There are two ways of doing it.
First - use `using` directive for a temporary local connection, e.g.:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    // some code here
}
```

But is seems that you store a reference to the connection in a field. In this case, the class that has this field should implement `IDisposable` and invoke `connection.Dispose()` in its own `Dispose` method:

```
class Repository : IDisposable
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

    void Dispose()
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But anyway you will need `using` here, the only difference - in `using` you will create `Repository` instead of `SqlConnection`

Comment: To open connection I am not using the 'using' statement. But all other places when I use the using directive to update, insert etc. I have added more code

Comment: Probably you should rewrite the code to open a connection each time you need to execute some SQL.

Answer (score 2):

> Do we need to close SQLite connection when exiting WP app?

The general rule is: If an object implements `IDisposable`, you should Dispose it or use a `using`.

```
using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("<ConnectionString>"))
{
...
}
```

There are only a few exceptions where it depends (like [DataSets and DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)).

> If we are to close the connection (Dispose() cuz I dont see a close
>   function) where do we close?

You don't have to ask this question if you use a `using`, because it will be Disposed automatically.

If you don't use `using`, then in most cases storing a connection and reusing it is not a good idea (except if you like errors), so the answer would be "as soon as possible".

**EDIT** (following OP)

> This is how I'm opening the connection in App.xaml.cs

1. You don't want to have anything related to DB connections in the view.
2. With the samples you provided, I don't see any advantage of doing so. You could simply open the connection every time.
3. If you worry about opening X connections, then take a look at the [following MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is about SqlConnections but the concept is the same for SQLiteConnections.

Comment: Sevrin. I've added snippets to the question to give you more clarity. I use the using directive for updating, inserting etc. But the connection which I opened in app.xaml.cs is left like that. :(