# What happens to DataRow objects when Dispose is called on a DataTable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, datarow

Here's where .NET starts to do my head in. Consider the following scenario:

1. I have a `DataTable` object, containing a number of `DataRow` objects
2. I add some of the `DataRow` objects to an Array
3. I call `Dispose` on the `DataTable`.

What guarantee do I have that calling `Dispose` on the `DataTable` won't compromise the `DataRow` objects (which, by reference, would affect those added to the Array)?

MS [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) is zero help in this case.

**EDIT:** So far folks have missed the point entirely. `IDisposable` objects are *meant* to be disposed of as soon as possible. My code is going to be creating thousands of `DataTable` objects during a typical day. No way am I leaving those un-disposed if they implement `IDispoable`.

*BUT*, I need the handful of `DataRow` objects to stay alive because that's what my 3rd-party binary (which I have no control over) expects. And I need them to stay alive for *significantly longer* than the `DataTable` objects.

All I need is authoritative information that describes what `Dispose` on a `DataTable` actually does. Looks like said information does not exist, which is why I'm asking here for help. Someone may have a reference, or documentation I have overlooked, that answers my need.

**EDIT 2:** I have tested as **Blam** suggested, including adding `GC.Collect` + a bonus `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` + one more `GC.Collect` after disposing the `DataTable`. The `DataRows` appear to be fine, still alive and accessible. That's positive, but alas *not authoritative enough* to include in production code :-(

Comment: What do you mean by "compromise"?  If you still want to use the `DataRow` objects then why are you disposing the `DataTable` that contains them in the first place?  Disposing something is only to be done when you have no further use of it.  If you do have further use for the `DataTable` then don't dispose it in the first place.

Comment: What do you gain in keeping the DataRows in an array?

Comment: @Tarik I gain compatibility with a method (3rd-party binary) that expects DataRows in an Array ;-)

Comment: @jmcilhinney. Exactly. I *don't* have any further use for the `DataTable`, I only have use for the handful of `DataRows` in the Array. That's why I want to Dispose of the `DataTable`, but only if it leaves the `DataRows` unaffected.

Comment: @Blam End-user testing to determine undocumented behaviors is dangerous. What is system configuration / resource pressures on another machine cause GC to behave differently or more aggressively than in my tests?

Comment: Did you test?  Did you call a GC.Collect?

Comment: @Blam You've got to be kidding. Is this how you code? Second-guessing someone else's hidden/undocumented behaviors by running your own tests is *not* going to result in robust, dependable apps.

Comment: @misha256 Are you kidding?  Is that how you go about not testing?  Did you test a Dispose and GC.Collect or not?

Comment: @Blam You're missing the point. What guarantee do I have that my test results would actually be correct (repeatable, dependable, system-agnostic, etc.)? Of course I test, we test all the time. But NOT to try to reverse-engineer undocumented behaviors. Like I said, that's dangerous and we don't do that. Why don't we just stick to my question which I now clarified.

Comment: Of course you test?  You give NO indication of what you have tested.  What is the problem with stating in the question what you have tested?

Comment: @Blam OK I concede! I have tested as you suggest, including adding `GC.Collect` + a bonus `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` + one more `GC.Collect` after disposing the `DataTable`. The `DataRows` appear to be fine, still alive and accessible. That's positive, but alas not authoritative enough to include in production code :-(

Answer (score 3):

`DataTable` doesn't re-implement `MarshalByValueComponent.Dispose`, and that method doesn't really do much on its own. So in effect, calling `DataTable.Dispose` doesn't do anything to the table or the data it contains. Interestingly enough, `DataTable` even goes so far to suppress finalization in the constructor, because [it doesn't hold unmanaged resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable).

Now, if you look at the definition for `DataRow`, you'll notice that it doesn't implement `IDisposable` (or anything for that matter), doesn't have a finalizer, etc. It does, however, have a dependency on the table (which it gets via the DataRowBuilder passed in the constructor). Normally in that sort of situation, you never want to call dispose on an owning object until absolutely no one needs it anymore, as it *could* result in side effects from that parent reference being disposed of already.

However, in this case calling dispose doesn't actually do anything and it doesn't matter either way. In fact, you're calling `Dispose` as a premature optimization that has little or no effect, so it's superfluous. Your `DataRow`s and the data they contain will be unaffected by calling dispose on the table.

(Sorry but not sorry the example is C# and not VB.NET, but there is no difference between the two in this example, except one is uglier than the other ;p )

```
var table = new DataTable();

table.RowDeleting += (sender, e) => {
     Console.WriteLine("Deleting");
};
table.Clear();
table.Columns.Add("Foo");
table.Columns.Add("Bar");

var row = table.NewRow();
row["Foo"] = "Hello";
row["Bar"] = "World";
table.Rows.Add(row);

table.Dispose(); // "Dispose call! We've got a Dispose call here!"

row.Delete(); // "See? No one cares."
```

I don't know what constitutes as *authoritative enough for production code*, but there you go.

Comment: Fascinating, thank you. You identified a dependency between `DataRows` and the parent `DataTable`. That's enough for me to step back and say *"you know what, we need to deep copy those rows so there's no dependency*. Even though your investigations demonstrate things would work fine in my case, there's no guarantee MS won't update the framework in the future and break that undocumented behavior.  Thanks again for a good constructive answer.

Comment: @misha256 If they changed it, it'd be a rather significant breaking change to that feature. This design also hasn't changed for a very long time (if ever), so I'd say it's rather stable. You're free to do what you want, of course, but I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score -2):

the data table will never get garbage collected. Dotnet will compile your code to keep that grid until the array is no longer referencing said row. The typical scenario I have seen is that until the parent object that created the grid and the array gets disposed of, the grid will stay around in the process marked for deletion but never garbage collected because it has a pending reference.

In other words, avoid doing it because typically it won't properly garbage collect the grid until the app is closed.

If it is unmanaged code it should blow up on first reference after dispose.