# WebForms Redirect DataTable Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, garbage-collection

Right not were trying to improve our system because we have memory leaks in our application. Im wondering what will happen if i created a DataTable object that i left undisposed then redirect to another page?

Will the DataTable object be garbage collected or not? (ASP WEBFORMS)
thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should worry about disposing DataTable, as per page life cycle the page object is disposed after unload event.

Additionally, DataTable is a managed object, so calling dispose manually will yield less benefit. Read below.

[Should I Dispose() DataSet and DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)