# object reference related resource are not dispose

Tags: c#

I am getting static code analysis error for below code,

**Object referenced by 'dsAlertsPointData' is lost, but related resource are not disposed.**

```
internal static void PrepareDataTables(List<AlertsData> processedAlertsData, out DataTable dtAlertsData, out DataSet dsMergedAlertsPointData)
    {
        var dsAlertsPointData = new DataSet();
        dsMergedAlertsPointData = new DataSet();
        dsMergedAlertsPointData.Tables.Add("AlertsPointData");

        dtAlertsData = processedAlertsData.ToDataTable();

        foreach (var singleAlert in processedAlertsData)
        {
            if (singleAlert.AlertsPointsData.Count > 0)
                dsAlertsPointData.Tables.Add(singleAlert.AlertsPointsData.ToDataTable());
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < dsAlertsPointData.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            dsMergedAlertsPointData.Tables["AlertsPointData"].Merge(dsAlertsPointData.Tables[i]);
        }
    }
```

What is the resolution for this?? Thanks!

Comment: Don't write out DataTable this line doesn't have any meaning. DataTable is class so you are transferring the value of the reference. Show the method which calls PrepareDataTable and tell us on which line the error happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use `using` block to dispose `dsAlertsPointData`. It will free the resources held by it at the end of `using` block.

```
using (var dsAlertsPointData = new DataSet())
{
    dsMergedAlertsPointData = new DataSet();
    dsMergedAlertsPointData.Tables.Add("AlertsPointData");

    dtAlertsData = processedAlertsData.ToDataTable();

    foreach (var singleAlert in processedAlertsData)
    {
        if (singleAlert.AlertsPointsData.Count > 0)
            dsAlertsPointData.Tables.Add(singleAlert.AlertsPointsData.ToDataTable());
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < dsAlertsPointData.Tables.Count; i++)
    {
        dsMergedAlertsPointData.Tables["AlertsPointData"].Merge(dsAlertsPointData.Tables[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still the same error, the related resource are not disposed.

Comment: add `using` blocks for  `dsMergedAlertsPointData` and `dtAlertsData` as well

Comment: I don't see any point to use Dispose on DataSet. DataSet are not IDisposable objects.

Comment: `DataSet` class derives from `MarshalByValueComponent` class which is an IDisposable object. You can call `Dispose` method for a `DataSet`.

Comment: The Dispose method in DataSet exists ONLY because of side effect of inheritance-- in other words, it doesn't actually do anything useful in the finalization.Here a question to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable