# What will happen to dataset when its table return inside the using statement

Tags: c#, mysql, memory-leaks, datatable, dataset

I''d like to know what will happen to dataset when its table is being returned within its using statement. Example a function with code as follow:

```
using tmpDataSet = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet(_connString, strSQL)
    if tmpDataSet is not nothing andalso tmpDataSet.Tables.Count > 0 then
        return tmpDataSet.Tables(0)
    end if
end using
```

I want to have a function which will provide me requested datatable, and will dispose the datatable whenever I am done playing with it. I just wonder, whether the dataset will be disposed properly while its table is being returned, as I do not want this will cause memory leak.

Comment: I suggest reading [Should I Dispose() Datasets and DataTables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable)