# How to resolve operand data type nvarchar is invalid for minus operator

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've a SQL query which tries to fetch all records that were created within the last one hour

```
string query = "select * from Monarchchangelog mcl  WHERE LOWER(mcl.mcl_usercomment) LIKE 'bolt%'  AND mcl.mcl_createtime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -@minutesBack, GETDATE())  ORDER BY mcl.mcl_createtime DESC";
string tablename = "NEW_UPDATES";
string minutesBack = "60"; //set by another function but for eg sake I've hardcoded the  value
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("minutesBack", minutesBack);
DataSet ds = RunQuery(command, tablename);
```

which I'm executing with the below code

```
private DataSet RunQuery(SqlCommand command, String tablename)
{
    DataSet ds = null;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = null;
    using (SqlConnection oc = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
    {
        try
        {
            oc.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = oc;
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, tablename);
        }
        catch
        {
            if (ds != null)
            {
                ds.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oc != null)
            {
                oc.Close();
                oc.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    return ds;
}
```

when I try to execute this code I'm getting the below error but `mcl_createtime` is of `datetime` datatype

> operand data type nvarchar is invalid for minus operator

Can someone let me know where am I going wrong
Thank you

Comment: `-@minutesBack` - you are passing this parameter as a string, not a number. Also highly recommended not to use [`AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @DaleK Can you let me know how to pass this parameter as a number and what is the best alternative to AddWithValue?

Comment: @m_beta There is an example on how to do it in the link Dale just gave you. In the link, after they describe the problem with the `AddWithValue` they tell you about the alternative. And yes, I am avoiding telling you the exact name of the function so you can have the useful information of the link and learn not only what function should you use, but also why you should do it.

Comment: also the whole point of the using() statement is so you don't have to write code to catch exception and manually dispose

Comment: @MitchWheat The `try-catch` does make sense, the [using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) in that code would only dispose the connection but not the `DataSet` OP disposes in the `catch`, what is unnecesary would be the `finally` (it would be in fact redundant because of the `using`).

Comment: @Cleptus: dispose is not necessary for a Dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913228/should-i-dispose-dataset-and-datatable . I write code using ADO.NET quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @DaleK's comment I resolved the issue, replaced the code

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("minutesBack", minutesBack);
```

with this piece

```
command.Parameters.Add("minutesBack", SqlDbType.Int).Value = minutesBack;
```

A good way of passing your parameters is by explicitly mentioning the sql datatype to avoid datatype issues like this. For more details please follow the link [AddWithValue vs Add](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

So I passed my parameter as a number and not a string, also got a good understanding of `try-catch`, `using` statements.
Good learning, thank you everyone for your contribution.