# Should I call Close on HttpWebResponse, even if it's inside a using statement?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, idisposable

I have some code like, this code is used **very** heavily:

```
using (HttpWebResponse r = _GetHttpWebResponse(uri, body, method, contentType, headers)) {
    /* do something with the response */

    /* call r.Close() explicitly? */
}
```

The code works fine today, but the connections to the server stay open for quite some time. (checked using TCPView)

Is there a benefit to calling the `Close()` method explicitly? Is it recommended, or maybe recommended not to do it, and why?

Comment: I guess this answers my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036/will-the-gc-call-idisposabledispose-for-me

Comment: No. Whether the finalizer calls dispose or not is a very different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have significant code inside the using after you have finished consuming the response then sure calling close is ok.  However you might want to consider refactoring your code so that code that doesn't need the response isn't inside the using block.

That said closeing the response doesn't necessarily close the connection. The HTTP/1.1 protocol makes provision for the connection to remain open to make subsequent requests quicker.

Comment: FWIW, The first sentence of this answer needs to be read carefully. It would be clearer to start out by explaining, as other answers do, that `using` does `close` for you - you don't need to call it yourself. Once you are clear about that, then you can understand what the sentence is saying:  if for some reason you want to `close` (to release resources) mid-way through the `using` block, then go ahead and do so - but a cleaner design would be to *only keep inside the using block, code that uses the result*.

Answer (score 30):

When `Dispose()` is called on `WebResponse` (`HttpWebReponse`'s base class), it calls it's `Close()` method for you.  A quick glance using Reflector confirms this.

Edit (in response to comment): If it's called for you already, why call it explicitly?  For the sake of clarity?  I think if people understand the `using (X x = ...)` statement, they'll understand that it is closing the underlying connection.  You gain nothing by calling it explicitly in this case.

Comment: I know it does, the question is if I should call .Close anyway

Comment: you're right, "using" calls the Dispose, GC calls the Finalize

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it.  Sorry it wasn't the right answer for ya.

Comment: can't accept two answers as correct, so I gave you a thumbs up, and accepted the other one

Answer (score 19):

The `using` keyword is a syntactic sugar for `try/finally` block, which wraps around your `HttpWebResponse`, since it implements `IDisposable`. When in the `finally` clause, it will call the `Dispose()` method, which will call `Close()`.
This means that you don't have to explicitly call the `Close()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Close is the method that implements IDisposable.Dispose, therefore there is definitely no need to call the Close method beforehand. It is fully redundant.

Comment: A method called "Close" cannot implement an interface member called "Dispose".  One can call the other, but they are distinct methods.

Comment: Not quite true. In VB.NET, this is actually possible. It's only in C# that it is (technically) not, though one can imitate it very easily.

Comment: I stand corrected.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533659/in-c-is-it-possible-to-implement-an-interface-member-using-a-member-with-a-dif