# Remove Class/Variable Instance from memory (completely)

Tags: c#, class, memory, memory-management, instance

I'm working on a socket project in c# (.NET). I'm handling data's with some classes (packets). When I'm looking memory usage if datas are incoming, it's going up! namely creating classes. How can I delete (manual) classes and unused variables/classes from memory (not with GC!)?

If I try basic things like only data receieve, it's going up again. At this point, I want to remove/delete the classes/variables from memory **completely**!

Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The GC _is_ what removes unused objects. If you don't want to use it I think you're stuck writing unmanaged code and doing it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit and pain (in some situations) that you *can nott* do that manually. Even forcing `GC.Collect()` you're not guaranteed to get a free memory.

Plus, the memory cleanup request is a *request*, so may happen with some delay, not immediately.

So the only way in `CLR`, **if we are talking about .NET objects allocations**, to cleanup memory is: clean your object(s), leave them without other object pointing to them , and

- wait untill `GC` will collect them, if will (depends on generation)
- manually call `GC.Collect()`, it's not suggested, but can be used too, by the way there is no gurantee that the memory will be cleaned.

For further reading: [what are the Generations in Garbage Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257563/what-are-the-generations-in-garbage-collection)

Comment: namely, i can only do this: 1:removeObject from arrayList, 2:set it "null". right? :L

Comment: @freaka61: Set what to null? There's no such concept of setting an object to null - only setting a variable value to null. If you don't already have a variable holding onto a reference to the object, what are you going to set to null?

Comment: @JonSkeet err, how can i delete instanced class? (how to GC can remove it?)

Comment: @freaka61: You don't delete it. The GC will delete it when it needs to. If you believe your objects are being retained for too long, use a profiler to find out if something else has a reference to it. I'm not sure how many more ways we can say the same thing.

Comment: @freaka61: it's enough that you cleanup array, and ensure that none else in the program points to the instance of it. Soon or later it *should* be collected.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. You don't get to delete objects manually in C#. If the garbage collector isn't doing this automatically, chances are you're holding onto the object somewhere. Use a profiler to find out where, and fix your code.

Comment: i'm using packets in a arrayList (or dictionary). if packet handled namely if it's processed, i want to delete it from memory. i have already remove it from ArrayList (or dictionary).

Comment: @freaka61: Then if nothing else is holding onto it, it *will* be garbage collected eventually. You **cannot** delete it from memory. It just doesn't happen. You need to accept that. (Also, why are you still using ArrayList?)