# Hash Array Mapped Tries Memory Allocation

Tags: c#, algorithm, memory, hashmap, hashtable

I'm reading this http://lampwww.epfl.ch/papers/idealhashtrees.pdf and at the end of page 5 in to page 6 he talks about having an array of 32 linked lists of free tables.

In the algorithm, when you add a node to a table, you resize by 1 and then append it.

I don't understand the benefit of having this linked list of free tables. What's the difference between pre-allocating them and allocating them on the fly? If you pre-allocate then you're wasting memory so the main benefit of a HAMT is defeated, and also you'll rapidly run out of pre-allocated tables to use so it was a waste from the start.

I just don't really understand that section of the paper at all. Either way you're allocating these arrays so how is this more complex version any better than simply re-allocating on demand? I'm coding this in C# by the way if it makes any difference regarding memory optimizations.

Comment: On quick glance article talks about keeping freed up blocks in that table - instead of releasing just resized block it stores it (no pre-allocation). So when asking for block of the same size one is already allocated... Note that even for .Net allocator it may be good strategy as for slowly growing hash table used blocks will move to Gen1/2 and if released afterwards will stay long time before garbage collected, other memory allocation systems may benefit even more due to higher cost of smaller allocations/significant problem with free space fragmentation.

Comment: Your first sentence made everything click. Thank you so much! I'm not sure what you mean by Gen1/2 though.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov is talking about garbage collector generations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257590/433249 is a good introduction on the topic.