# Which generation static readonly member will be allocated in

Tags: c#, .net

Having this code

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly int[] s_numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (int number in s_numbers)
            {
                WriteLine(number);
            }

            WriteLine("Press ENTER to close the app.");
            ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering where `s_numbers` array will be allocated (which generation) ? 
My reasoning is the following - since this is `static` `readonly` member it is not going to be `nulled`, so it is not going to be `GC'd` for the lifetime of `AppDomain`. Hence it makes sense to put it into GEN2 straight away (like with large objects) and not allocate it in GEN0 & then move it from GEN0 up until GEN2.
Unfortunately, I couldn't confirm if this is the case (I can't find this array using WinDbg).

So to reiterate the question - which GC generation will this `static readonly` member be allocated in ?

Comment: it's only used once, the optimiser may think otherwise.

Comment: Since the only way to allocate memory in the normal managed heap is to increment the high water mark in GEN0, how are you proposing that your "optimization" gets something straight into GEN2?

Comment: @Rob so it is GEN0 in this case, what if it would have been used from other places (through public readonly property) ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so how does it do it for large objects ? Or are you saying large objects also get allocated in GEN0 first and eventually get promoted to GEN2 through GCs ?

Comment: No, large objects have a dedicated heap (LOH)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever [which is in GEN2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) right ? `Newly allocated objects form a new generation of objects and are implicitly generation 0 collections, **unless they are large objects, in which case they go on the large object heap in a generation 2 collection**`

Comment: They're *considered* to be in GEN2 but they're not *allocated* in the same manner. They don't live in the same piece of address space as the (non-large) GEN2 objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readonly` is a lie. What you consider `readonly` is largely just a *guideline*, not an actual rule - at least in most runtimes:

```
private static void ThisWorksFine()
{
    typeof(Program).GetField("s_numbers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
        .SetValue(null, null);
}
```

No optimization currently exists to check for this "assigning to a readonly static field" scenario and allocate the array in GEN2. Could it? Maybe. I'd wager it isn't worth the complexity, for a very limited number of allocations / objects. It doesn't exist today, so it follows the usual allocation / promotion rules.

Answer (score 2):

[Part of Adriaan Stander‘s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257590/2867756)

From [Understanding garbage collection in .Net](http://aspalliance.com/828)

> When an object is first created, it is put into generation 0. When the generation 0 is filled up, the garbage collector is invoked. The objects that survive the garbage collection in the first generation are promoted onto the next higher generation, generation 1. The objects that survive garbage collection in generation 1 are promoted onto the next and the highest generation, generation 2. This algorithm works efficiently for garbage collection of objects, as it is fast. Note that generation 2 is the highest generation that is supported by the garbage collector

So it won’t start on GEN2 immediately it will go GEN0->GEN1->GEN2.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Question is not about how GC works in general, but if there are any optimizations for `static readonly` members.

Comment: @Michael: Just out of interest, why you want to know that at all? Do you implement your own garbage collector?

Comment: He is either just curious or might be trying to be a better programmer, that writes runtime and memory efficient code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter very good question. Imagine you have a method that is being called quite frequently, and inside the method you initalize static array (data is static there). As soon as you're done with method invocation it is not needed, so it can be GCd. I was thinking if making this array as `static readonly` will be a good optimization in terms of not putting much pressure on GC and working memory set.

Comment: @Michael ultimately it is a single object/reference; in the grand scheme of things, it isn't worth getting excited about - any saving there will be lost in the noise

Comment: @Toxantron: if you want to be a better programmer you should not optimize your code for implementation details of the garbage collector that might change tomorrow. You should optimize your code for readability and it should work. If that array eats your memory consider to use a database.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know what you are getting at, but I have seen beautiful working code, that was terribly slow and then I would disagree. And understanding the tool your work with DOES make you a better programmer. One array won't make a difference, but overall being conscious about performance made a huge difference for us at least.
For example we had colleagues constantly calling `ToArray` to avoid enumeration exception and that is a plain waste of resources.