# Why Garbage collector have only 3 generations, not more or less?

Tags: c#, .net

As i have gone through **Garbage Collection (GC)** and its **generation(0,1,2)**.
The question strikes to me that, why Microsoft decided to keep it to 3?

Why **not to less than 3 or more than 3** ? I need some logical explanation.

Comment: Because that is the way it was designed. Even if we have an answer from someone at Microsoft who has implemented the GC, the answer is still likely to be "primarily opinion based."

Comment: As far as I remember the term 'generation'  is rather misleading anyway..

Comment: As to what a Generation means: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257590/9363973. And as to why MS decided on 3 generations: Ask whoever designed it

Comment: Try to think it by a functional point of view: we have short-living objects (gen 0), medium-term living ones (gen 1), and an indefinitely old-aged items (gen 2). This design aims to have good efficiency in garbage collection, balancing its performance impact with the need to release (and defrag) memory allocation.

Comment: It's like asking, I need a logical argument for why me colleague commutes by a certain route, why doesn't he turn right there or left here, why doesn't he catch the bus, taxi or train? First, it doesn't matter, unless he fails to get to work on time, and it is up to them how they do it. Second, they obviously choose the route that tends to get them there, quickly enough, without too much effort. Third, the only person that can sensibly answer is the colleague.

Comment: Patrick Dussud, the author of the .NET collector, explains it well in [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/E2E-Erik-Meijer-and-Patrick-Dussud-Inside-Garbage-Collection).  Worth a complete watch, you can skip to 14:45 to hear him talking about the role of gen#1 and why he didn't consider adding more ephemeral generations.  In a nutshell, gen#1 helps to avoid promoting temporary objects that were in flight by accident when the collection was triggered.  Adding more didn't make it more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the documentation,

> [**Generations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#generations)
>
> The heap is organized into generations so it can handle
>   long-lived and short-lived objects. Garbage collection primarily
>   occurs with the reclamation of short-lived objects that typically
>   occupy only a small part of the heap. There are three generations of
>   objects on the heap:
>
> **Generation 0.**
>
> This is the youngest generation and contains short-lived
>   objects. An example of a short-lived object is a temporary variable.
>   Garbage collection occurs most frequently in this generation.
>
> Newly allocated objects form a new generation of objects and are
>   implicitly generation 0 collections, unless they are large objects, in
>   which case they go on the large object heap in a generation 2
>   collection.
>
> Most objects are reclaimed for garbage collection in generation 0 and
>   do not survive to the next generation.
>
> **Generation 1.**
>
> This generation contains short-lived objects and serves
>   as a buffer between short-lived objects and long-lived objects.
>
> **Generation 2.**
>
> This generation contains long-lived objects. An example
>   of a long-lived object is an object in a server application that
>   contains static data that is live for the duration of the process.
>
> Garbage collections occur on specific generations as conditions
>   warrant. Collecting a generation means collecting objects in that
>   generation and all its younger generations. A generation 2 garbage
>   collection is also known as a full garbage collection, because it
>   reclaims all objects in all generations (that is, all objects in the
>   managed heap).

We can see that **Generation 2** is for objects that should last for the duration of the process. It is not sensible to model objects that can live longer than the process, at least on operating systems I know about.

I suspect that there is not a greater granularity of generations because it would prove more cumbersome than the benefits derived. Any extrapolation on that concept is pure conjecture without real world performance testing.

I suspect even a canonical answer from a designer of the GC would be prone to speculation but they may be able to detail how that level of granularity  was reckoned.

Answer (score 0):

Generally All the newly created objects will be placed only in geneartion_0 not in other generations when the geneartion_0 was out of memory then CLR will perform an operation known as Collection.

Collection operation have 2 phases marking phase and compact phase .

In marking phase CLR will mark  which objects are in use and which objects are not in use

In Compact phase objects which are in use will be moved to next generation by CLR and objects which are not in use will be removed.

At the Initial stages of garbage collector development microsoft  has used 10 generations but 10 generations was completely useless and burden to the system because of the following reasons

1. 94-96% of the collection  operation has done with in the generation_0 only i.e..
   most of the time(90-95%) the collection operation was performed on
   generation_0
2. 2-3% of the collection  operation has done with in the generation_0 and generation_1 only i.e.. at a time collection operation was performed on both generation_0 and generation_1

3)1 or <1% of the collection  operation has done with in the generation_0 and generation_1 and generation_2

So 3 generations are enough to manage the newly created objects and this is the reason why garbage collector will have 3 generations only

Refered from CLR Via C# by Jeffrey Richter 4th edition 2012 version