# Will SqlConnection get disposed by GC?

Tags: .net, idisposable, sqlconnection, finalizer

**Disclaimer:** I know `IDisposable` should be implemented when dealing with unmanaged resources.  The rest of the code should be deterministic and do `using (...) { }` (equivalent of `try {} finally { Dispose(); }`) to guarantee a cleanup as soon as possible.  Also, the GC will [not call `Dispose()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036/will-the-gc-call-idisposable-dispose-for-me), so the recommended pattern is to override the `Finalize()` method (in C# using the destructor syntax) which then calls `Dispose()`.  The GC will usually call `Finalize()` (unless `GC.SuppressFinalize()` has been called).

**Problem:** So now that I got that out of the way, I have an odd scenario where I cannot do `using (SqlConnection...) { }` due to code out of my control.  I can usually do a deterministic `Dispose()`, but can't guarantee it.  I used Reflector to disassemble `SqlConnection` and see that it uses Dispose(), but unless I'm blind there is no finalizer/destructor (`Finalize()` or `~SqlConnection()`).  Does that mean that the GC will not "clean up" (send back to the pool) the connection in the odd case I can't?  I haven't been able to find anything definitive...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, it won't get disposed, as finalisation is not disposal.

There is a finaliser in `System.ComponentModel.Component`, but its suppressed in `SQLConnection`'s constructor. This is a good idea if you inherit from something with a finaliser that you know with 100% certainty you won't need, but a bad idea otherwise. In this case it's a good idea.

Remember though, that `SqlConnection` is a wrapper on a "real" connection. Indeed, it's most likely a wrapper on a changing set of objects which represent different connection states. This is part of the mechanism that allows for the "real" connection to be pooled efficiently, as each time you call `Open()` it obtains the relevant object from the pool, and every time you call `Close()` (whether directly, by `Dispose()` or by leaving the scope of a `using`) it returns it.

Now, remember that only objects that directly hold an unmanaged resource or something otherwise not the GC's concern, need to be finalised. `SqlConnection` holds an object that may (depending on the state of `SqlConnection`) be one that holds an unmanaged resource (or indeed, deeper through the nest of classes). There is therefore no need for `SqlConnection` to itself be finalised. Consider the three possible ways an open `SqlConnection` can stop being an open `SqlConnection`:

1. `Close()` is called. This immediately returns the real connection to the pool (or closes it if there is no pooling).
2. `Dispose()` is called. This calls `Close()` with the same effect.
3. The object gets garbage collected.

Now, in the third case, the object holds a reference to the object that has the real connection. It also is the only object that does so. That object is hence also going to be garbage collected. If it has a finaliser (which it probably does, though I'm not going to assume there aren't further clever tricks going on) then that finaliser will cause it to be placed into the finaliser queue, and it will be eventually finalised.

If `SqlConnection` had a finaliser, the only real effects would be:

1. Potential for buggy code (dealing with finalisable members in finaliser code is fraught, as you don't know whether or not they've been finalised).
2. Potential for slowing things up (the real connection is going to be finalised anyway, at best we're just slowing up the finalisation and GC).
3. Nothing to do here anyway (the real connection will be finalised without any help here).

So, putting a finaliser on the `SqlConnection` is a lose without a win. Also, your real connection should hopefully be eventually finalised.

This said, it's still far from ideal and still **very** likely to leak connections. Could you detail precisely why you can't call `Close()` or dispose yourself? Could the code managing the connection not call close for you (the object should end its days *somewhere*, and should be closed there)?

Do you need to keep it alive for an `IDataReader` or an object that feeds from an `IDataReader` to be allowed to complete? In which case, could you use the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` flag so that closing (or disposing of) the reader closes the connection? This latter case is about the only case where I can recall ever having to let a connection leave scope un-disposed.

Comment: "SqlConnection holds an object that may (depending on the state of SqlConnection) be one that holds an unmanaged resource" - good point, I didn't verify that SqlConnection actually holds the unmanaged resource.  Basically, the code managing the connection is an external library that wasn't properly implemented.  I think I'll be able to make changes to it after all and avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: Glad to hear that. The matter of finalisation being done on the right object is all well and good, but won't help you if finalisation doesn't happen frequently enough (and IME it almost never does - or worse, much worse, it does in test and not live).

Comment: +1 good answer. Im a little bit confused about following statement on msdn which suggests that SqlConnection is a managed resource. "Do not call Close or Dispose on a Connection, a DataReader, or any other **managed** object in the Finalize method of your class." from [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter the `SqlConnection` class is indeed a managed object, which wraps the unmanaged object (through a few managed levels of indirection) that does the actual transmitting of 1s and 0s. And yes, never dispose within a finaliser (barring the rare case of your knowing the managed object SHOULD have its own finaliser but DOES NOT have its own finaliser). Generally doing this will mess with the finaliser of that object, and should also be unnecessary because of said finaliser in that other object.