# Memory Management Of Unmanaged Component By CLR

Tags: c#

I am having a little confusion , may be this question is very silly one.

where does the memory allocated for a unmanaged component?

In my .net code if i initiated an unmanaged component, where this component is going to be loaded and memory is allocated ?

How CLR marshall call between Managed and Unmanaged heap ?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your reply but what i am asking is say suppose i do a DLLIMPORT of User32.Dll , this is clearly a unmanaged dll and i call some function in User32.DLL now my question , how CLR marshall my call to this unmanged dll?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It starts out pretty easy.  The pinvoke marshaller first calls LoadLibrary and passes the DLL name you specified, the DllImportAttribute.Value property.  In your case, user32.dll is already loaded because it gets loaded by the .NET bootstrapper, its reference count just gets incremented.  But normally the Windows loader gets the DLL mapped into the address space of the process so the exported functions can be called.

Next is GetProcAddress to get the address of the function to call, the DllImportAttribute.EntryPoint property.  The marshaller makes a couple of tries unless you used ExactSpelling.  A function name like "foo" is tested several possible ways, foo and fooW or fooA.  Nasty implementation detail of Win32 related to the difference between Unicode and Ansi characters.  The CharSet property matters here.

Now I need to wave hands a bit because it gets tricky.  The marshaller constructs a stack frame, setting up the arguments that need to be passed to the exported function.  This requires low level code, carefully excluded from prying eyes.  Take it at face value that it performs the kind of translations that the Marshal class supports to convert between managed and unmanaged types.  The DllImportAttribute.CallingConvention property matters here because that determines what argument value needs to be place where so that the called function can read it properly.

Next it sets up an SEH exception handler so that hardware exceptions raised by the called code can be caught and translated into a managed exception.  The one that generates the more common one, AccessViolationException.  And others.

Next, it pushes a special cookie on the stack to indicate that unmanaged code is about to start using stack.  This prevents the garbage collector from blundering into unmanaged stack frames and interpret the pointers it finds there as managed object references.  You can see this cookie back in the debugger's call stack, [Managed to Native Transition].

Next, just an indirect call to the function address as found with GetProcAddress().  That gets the unmanaged code running.

After the call, cleanup might need to be done to release memory that was allocated to pass the unmanaged arguments.  The return value might need to be translated back to a managed value.  And that's it, assuming nothing nasty happened, execution continues on the next managed code statement.

Answer (score 8):

Unmanaged memory allocations come from the process heap. You are responsible for allocating/deallocating the memory, since it will not get garbage collected because the GC does not know about these objects.

Comment: You might want to create a wrapper around the unmanaged component, and implement the `IDisposable` interface, for a cleaner way of deallocating it. The garbage collector calls the function defined in this interface to prevent from "forgetting" to clean up.

Comment: You could wrap it in IDisposable, but be sure that you call Dispose or override the finalizer. Just implementing IDispose is not enough, the GC does not call Dispose, it calls Object.Finalize (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036/will-the-gc-call-idisposable-dispose-for-me)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an academic piece of info expanding on what has been posted here:

There are about 8 different heaps that the CLR uses:

1. Loader Heap: contains CLR structures and the type system
2. High Frequency Heap: statics, MethodTables, FieldDescs, interface map
3. Low Frequency Heap: EEClass, ClassLoader and lookup tables
4. Stub Heap: stubs for CAS, COM wrappers, P/Invoke
5. Large Object Heap: memory allocations that require more than 85k bytes
6. GC Heap: user allocated heap memory private to the app
7. JIT Code Heap: memory allocated by mscoreee (Execution Engine) and the JIT compiler for managed code
8. Process/Base Heap: interop/unmanaged allocations, native memory, etc

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Part of your question is answered by Michael. I answer the other part.

If CLR loaded into an unmanaged process, it is called CLR hosting. This usually involves calling an entry point in mscoree DLL and then the default AppDomain is loaded. In such a case, CLR asks for a block of memory from the process and when given, that becomes its memory space and will have a stack and heap.