# Subscribing Events in C# Code

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I converted a piece of code from VB to C#. The UI in VB has a button **ButNewOrder**. 
On click of the button , the below method gets executed in VB code

```
 Public Sub mnuFileNewJob_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles ButNewOrder.Click
        Dim ErrorFlag As ErrorFlagType = InitErrorFlag()
        Try
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor
            StatusText = "Loading New Job."
            LoadNewSoftJob(Me)
            System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorFlag.NumErrors += 1
            ReDim Preserve ErrorFlag.ErrorDef(ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1)
            With ErrorFlag.ErrorDef(ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1)
                .Description = "Error Loading New Job: " + ex.Message
                .Number = ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1
            End With
        End Try
        If ErrorFlag.NumErrors > 0 Then
            Dim ErrFrm As New FrmErrList
            ErrFrm.ErrorFlag = ErrorFlag
            ErrFrm.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
```

The above code when I convert to C#, I get this

```
public void mnuFileNewJob_Click(System.Object eventSender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.ErrorFlagType ErrorFlag = FrontEndStructures.InitErrorFlag();
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
                ModSoftFrontEndGlobalVariables.StatusText = "Loading New Job.";
                frmMain main = new frmMain();
                MainMod.LoadNewSoftJob(this);// I think I need to replace this with the form name
                System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorFlag.NumErrors += 1;
                Array.Resize(ref ErrorFlag.ErrorDef, ErrorFlag.NumErrors);
                var _with1 = ErrorFlag.ErrorDef[ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1];
                _with1.Description = "Error Loading New Job: " + ex.Message;
                _with1.Number =Convert.ToInt16( ErrorFlag.NumErrors - 1);
            }
            if (ErrorFlag.NumErrors > 0)
            {
                FrmErrList ErrFrm = new FrmErrList();
                ErrFrm.ErrorFlag = ErrorFlag;
                ErrFrm.Show();
            }
        }
```

Clicking on the Button in C# application is not resulting in anything. Double click on the button generates the following stub which means that there is nothing hooked up on the click event of the button.

```
private void ButNewOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I want to know how to let my button execute the same function as that of VB code?

Comment: In ButNewOrder click event bind mnuFileNewJob_Click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the C# version of VB's `AddHandler` statement:

`ButNewOrder.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.mnuFileNewJob_Click);`

This line of code is traditionally added to your `InitializeComponent()` method by the form designer, but technically you can put it just about anywhere. You'll get best results by putting it near where your form starts up.

Comment: I dont see the same thing happenning in VB code. I compared the designers but VB designer also doesnt have definition for the click event of the button.

Comment: @Apoorv: VB uses the `Handles` clause, which is the equivalent.

Comment: your code works bro but just wanted to know that why the VB designer didnt have that click event ?

Comment: It does; it just wires it up using the 'Handles' clause instead of the `AddHandler` statement. `ButNewOder.Click += this.mnuFileNewJob_Click;` is C#'s parity with VB's `AddHandler`. C# doesn't have parity with `Handles`.

Comment: and this VB code does in code behind ? I have one more question. When i m clicking on the close button present on the top right, the page is not closing ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113334/), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912836/) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318876/) for ideas about your form closure problem.

Comment: By code behind you must mean the designer partial class. No, C# does it in the designer. VB, with its `Handles` clause, is able to do it in the main class (as indicated in the code you posted).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116778/discussion-between-apoorv-and-intexx).

Comment: @Apoorv: If my answer solved your problem, would you mark it as such. If not, let me know and I'll continue to try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either navigate to Properties->Events (events is represented as a bolt) in Visual Studio when your button is selected and select, in the click event dropdown, your method.

Or add this in the Constructor:

```
ButNewOrder += mnuFileNewJob_Click
```

Alternatively, you can navigate to the designer code of your window (into `InitializeComponent()`), and replace `ButNewOrder += ButNewOrder_Click` with `ButNewOrder += mnuFileNewJob_Click`

Comment: its a WinForms based project. Where do I find Events here?

Comment: @Apoorv You click onto your button once, then there is a bolt at the bottom right in the properties window. If there is no properties window, rightclick the button and press properties