# Cancelling tasks in the Dispose method

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, idisposable

I have a class which spawns various tasks which can run indefinitely.  When this object is disposed, I want to stop those tasks from running.

Is this the correct approach:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    // Stuff

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            queueCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            feedCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're on the right track. However, I would suggest waiting for the task to terminate before returning from the `Dispose` method, in order to avoid race conditions where the task continues to operate after the object has been disposed. Also dispose the `CancellationTokenSource`.

**Update**: If you're on .NET Core 3.0 or later, you should make your class implement [`IAsyncDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncdisposable) and await your task from the `DisposeAsyncCore` method. I've updated the example below to reflect this.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MyClass : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource feedCancellationTokenSource =
        new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly Task feedTask;

    public MyClass()
    {
        feedTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!feedCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                // do finite work
            }
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            feedCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            feedTask.Wait();

            feedCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            feedTask.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);
        Dispose(false);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        feedCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        await feedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);

        feedCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
        feedTask.Dispose();
    }
}

// Sample usage:
public static class Program
{
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        await using (new MyClass())
        {
            // do something else
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks.  One question: why do you dispose of the task?

Comment: Just because it's safe to do so, since you're guaranteed that the task would have terminated by then. But [you don't really need to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx).

Comment: This works great if the object is disposed manually, or is used within a using block. However if the user locally creates MyClass within a method, the task continues running even when the method returns. I realize that the GC may execute at some time after the method finishes, however even minutes later the task is still running. 
I tried adding:

~MyClass()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

and this does get called when the application shuts down, but at that stage obviously skips the task cancel/dispose (correctly). Will the GC ever dispose or only finalize?

Comment: Regarding my comment above: It would seem that the GC will only call the Finalizer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036/will-the-garbage-collector-call-idisposable-dispose-for-me
However, this means that even if the GC eventually decides to call the Finalizer, that it doesn't stop the task.
Would it make sense to add ~MyClass() { Dispose(false); } AND also null the references to feedCancellationTokenSource and feedTask outside the if(disposing) block? This would cause an exception in the task - but at least it would stop! (I realize its not recommended to stop the task in the finalizer)

Comment: @phil_rawlings: The GC will only call the finalizer. You really can't do much during the finalizer calls: Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_1): “DO NOT access any finalizable objects in the finalizer code path, because there is significant risk that they will have already been finalized. For example, a finalizable object A that has a reference to another finalizable object B cannot reliably use B in A’s finalizer, or vice versa. Finalizers are called in a random order (short of a weak ordering guarantee for critical finalization).”

Comment: @phil_rawlings: I personally wouldn't bother with stopping the task from the finalizer. Consumers are *expected* to abide by the contract of calling `Dispose` on `IDisposable` instances; failing to do so is effectively a programming error on their part. I would specifically recommend against setting `feedCancellationTokenSource` to null; an unhandled exception from a task could tear down your whole process under certain configurations.

Comment: @phil_rawlings: If you really need to address this, I assume you could introduce a simple `volatile bool` sentinel flag which is set from the finalizer and observed from the task (along with or instead of the `feedCancellationTokenSource`). However, there might be some implications I'm missing. This is probably a good candidate for another SO question.

Comment: Asked new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447462/cancelling-a-task-when-an-object-is-finalized

Comment: 9 years later: is this a good pattern? You're calling `Wait` in the dispose path, thus blocking cleanup. That might have a significant performance hit.

Comment: @JHBonarius: I've updated the example to use `IAsyncDisposable` (which has been introduced since then). Whether you want to await the `Task` at all or just fire-and-forget its disposal depends on the actual use-case.