# c# fastest way to reset a socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I use this code to reset a socket when I get an error sending or receiving.

```
try {
  socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
  socket.Close();
  socket.Dispose(); 
} catch(Exception) {
}
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(ep)
```

I want to know if I can skip Shutdown, Close, and Dispose so I can get reconnected faster?  The garbage collector will eventually call those, right?

Comment: Are you sure those methods are taking appreciable time to run?

Comment: If you want something faster (but I can't see any benefit on this, some milliseconds will make no difference at all), copy the reference to the old socket, create the new socket, connect and then destroy the old one. You will not get anything faster than that.

Comment: *"the garbage collector will eventually call those, right?"* - nope

Comment: @Nate I've read a lot of comments and questions all over stack overflow that imply these might block in certain cases.  Sometimes these block for minutes.

Comment: @James the garbage collector will call Dispose(), and that probably calls some sort of shutdown?

Comment: @johnnycrash *"the garbage collector will call Dispose()"* - a common [misconception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036/will-the-garbage-collector-call-idisposable-dispose-for-me).

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests you have some misunderstanding about how to use sockets.

The `Shutdown()` method is not the same as the `Close()` method. They both are required. The `Shutdown()` method is what you use to inform the remote endpoint that you're done sending. Once both ends have shutdown the socket, *then* you can close the socket. Not before.

The `Close()` method is there to free up the unmanaged resources, i.e. the Windows socket handle that the .NET `Socket` class abstracts. Call this method only after you have gracefully shutdown the connection, or after an exception occurs while using the socket (at which point, the socket is no longer usable).

You don't need to call `Dispose()` at all. All it does is call the `Close()` method. Alternatively, call `Dispose()` instead of calling `Close()`. Either is fine. You don't need to call both.

It is true that if you call neither `Close()` nor `Dispose()`, at some point the garbage collector *might* get around to finalizing the object, which will dispose it for you. But that's not guaranteed, not when it will happen nor even *if* it will ever happen.

Note that if you want to reconnect faster, you need to do the graceful shutdown, even though it seems like that's more work. If you just close the socket, or you close it after calling `Shutdown()` but before waiting for the remote endpoint to also shutdown the connection, your socket will wind up in a waiting state that prevents reuse of that port and socket resources. The *fastest* way to reset your connection state and get reconnected again is to use the API *correctly*.

I always recommend to people new to the socket API to read the [Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/). It's not written for the .NET audience, but almost all of the information there is critically useful to anyone trying to learn how to use *any* network socket API.

Comment: I'm going to read the FAQ, thanks.  I use the socket to connect to Redis.  The code is async so only one socket handles millions of msgs an hour.  Occasionally the connection hiccups.  I get an error sending or receiving.  I can create a new socket object, connect it, and continue.  I am looking for the surefire way to disconnect that works in all situations, including when the socket is broken.

Comment: What happens when the other end is misbehaving or unreachable and doesn't respond to ShutDown()?

Comment: You can timeout the socket if you need to. Just be aware that there may be a delay in being able to re-establish the connection when you do this. Of course, if the other endpoint is in fact unreachable, a delay doesn't matter because you won't be able to reconnect anyway.