# Understanding how using block dispose of objects

Tags: c#, scope, dbcontext, idisposable

I have the following code, where I want to immediately dispose of `ApplicationDbContext` instance:

```
using (var context = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
{
    MyRepository myRespository = new MyRepository(context);
    myRepository.ReadData();
}
```

If C# garbage collector wants to immediately dispose of `ApplicationDbContext`, it would have to immediately dispose of `MyRepository` as well, because it has a reference to `ApplicationDbContext`? Is this actually happening?

Or do I need to write my code like below to ensure `ApplicationDbContext` is Disposed, immediately?

```
using (var context = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
using (MyRepository myRespository = new MyRepository(context))
{
    myRepository.ReadData();
}
```

Comment: read this: https://gunnarpeipman.com/csharp-idisposable/

Comment: `IDisposable` has nothing to do with the GC. There are lots of questions and answers on SO about this (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45036/will-the-garbage-collector-call-idisposable-dispose-for-me)) - just search and read!

Comment: Is `MyRepository` disposable?

Comment: Basic rule I use: Is the class or object Disposable (implements `IDisposable`)? If yes, then apply a `using` or a `try...finally` block. If your own class uses disposable resources as a global variable, make your own class disposable.

Comment: @OlivierRogier: Yes, MyRepository implements IDisposable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second block of code is right.

One using clause is applied to one declaration.

Wat you wrote here:

```
using (var context = ApplicationDbContext.Create())
using (MyRepository myRespository = new MyRepository(context))
{
  myRepository.ReadData();
}
```

Is the same as:

```
var context = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
try
{
  var myRespository = new MyRepository(context);
  try
  {
    myRepository.ReadData();
  }
  finally
  {
    myRepository.Dispose();
  }
}
finally
{
  context.Dispose();
}
```

That's what the compiler generate for you, therefore you do not need to worry about writing such a heavy and repetitive thing which is a possible source of error and bugs.

In the first code, `myRespository` is not disposed.